# English numeral calculator

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Write a calculator that takes input in a verbal form (as one might speak an equation) and also outputs in a verbal form (as one might speak a number).

## Rules

The calculator should be able to:

- add, subtract, multiply and divide
- handle operands between negative one million and one million
- handle outputs between negative one billion and one billion
- handle decimal points in its input and place them correctly in its output
- handle decimal output to the hundredths place, rounding where needed

All operations yielding fractional results should round to the nearest hundredths place (identically to the output formatting).

Report with output "E" (for error) when input would cause the program to fail due to being incorrectly formatted or dividing by 0; basically, the program shouldn't crash on bad input, because that would be a lousy calculator.

The calculator is *allowed*, but *not required* to report errors when operands or output escape their bounds.  This is meant to simplify the problem, but if you disagree with me, feel free to make a calculator capable of correctly handling greater operands and outputs without reporting errors.

Output "E" in the event that an operand for an operation exceeds the bounds defined for operands.

Output "E" in the event that the output exceeds the bounds described for outputs

How the program handles case-sensitivity and whitespace are left up to the golfer, as is the choice of British or American English.[<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals)

Programs that bypass the implementation of the calculator by using a language or library that has already implemented the functionality described above will be ineligible for victory.

## Winner

The program with the lowest number of characters wins.

## Examples

**Input:** two plus two
**Output:** four

**Input:** twenty-one point five minus one point five
**Output:** twenty

**Input:** one minus two
**Output:** negative one

**Input:** five times five
**Output:** twenty-five

**Input:** twenty-five divided by five
**Output:** five

**Input:** two plus two minus five times five divided by negative zero point five
**Output:** ten

**Input** one million times one thousand
**Output:** one billion

**Input:** one million times one thousand plus one
**Output:** E

**Input:** two million plus one million
**Output:** E

**Input:** one million plus one million plus one million
**Output:** E

Comment: What's the order of evaluation you're using? Normally, `two plus two minus five times five divided by negative zero point five` -> `2 + 2 - 5 * 5 / -0.5` -> `54`.

Comment: @marinus looks like strictly left-to-right. Thanks for noting

Comment: do we _have_ to fail for `one million one` on the input or `one billion one` on the output? Also, does the 1e6 limit or the 1e9 limit apply to intermediate results as well?

Comment: is the correct output for 1001 `one thousand and one`, or `one thousand one` will suffice?

Comment: should we consider `twelve hundred` as must-support input, must-fail input or won't-happen input? What about `thirty-six hundred`?

Comment: In general, is it okay to accept input other than what is specified above, and treat it however one wants? For instance, am I allowed to treat `twenteen` as an, ahem, nonstandard way of expressing 12?

Comment: @FireFly remember you'll have to be able to output `twenty` correctly. `twenteen` is never a valid output, so why accept it at input?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think it might allow simplifications of the input handling (namely, avoiding a comparison). Regardless, the question still stands whether one has to reject things that aren't proper english words for numerals or operations.

Comment: if we take the literal interpretation, then you may accept any input as valid as long as you know it doesn't represent a number outside the valid range.

Comment: Are we to use short scale? If that is the case, the test case `two million times one million` would yield `E` even without proper operand-magnitude checking (which I'm guessing is what it was meant to test for).

Comment: @marinus Jan has it correct, strictly left-to-right; like a normal calculator it does calculations as they are fed in.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm going to say it isn't necessary to fail on anything (input, output, intermediary results) so long as you can deliver the correct output; the purpose of the failure was to make it easier on people to be honest.

Comment: @FireFly I'm afraid I'm going to insist on only using proper English words; as Jan's questions are showing, there are already plenty of ambiguities to clarify as is. :)

Comment: @FireFly Short scale.  Somebody edited the last two tests for some reason, they should be plus, not times, as they were demonstrating failure on too large input and failure on too large an intermediary value; not that failure is necessary, but if you are going to fail, there's a test for you.

Comment: @JanDvorak Either one thousand and one or one thousand one are acceptable, but whichever format is chosen must be handled correctly as input.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure I see the difference between twelve hundred and thirty-six hundred; anyhow, let's call it "won't happen" input, but it is not an error to handle it correctly or to use that style for output.

Comment: You talk about supporting decimals but you don't properly specify how they are to be handled. What would the correct output be for `one hundred divided by three point nought`? (Also, why is the output of the final example `E` rather than `three million`?)

Comment: @PeterTaylor The final example is E because an intermediary value exceeds the bounds required to be acceptable by the calculator; the second plus is adding two million plus one million.  I admit I hadn't thought about repeating decimals; I suppose "thirty-three point three repeating" would be acceptable to me.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Having thought more about the repeating decimals issue, I think it would be best to avoid it by restricting output to the hundredths place; otherwise we get into issues of detecting repeating patterns, which while interesting, is probably a little too much work on top of what is already needed.  The next question then is whether to round output, and the answer is yes.

Comment: Are we required to worry about floating-point precision?

Comment: @JeffGohlke Let's have each operation's result be rounded to the hundredths place, just like the final output will be.  So "two divided by three times two" will output "one point three four", not "one point three three", because the intermediary .6666 repeating will be rounded to .67 before being multiplied.

Comment: Is it acceptable to [round half away from zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero)?

Comment: @grc Feel free to pick whatever commonly used tie-breaking method off that page you want, so long as you're rounding to the hundredths place.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, this is totally cheaty, and not complete to the specs.

*requires the `--disable-web-security` flag on chrome, +22*

## Javascript 509 + 22 = 531

```
x=new XMLHttpRequest;y=Object.keys(x);b=alert;q="querySelectorAll";s="send";x[y[3]]="document";x.open("GET","http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="+escape(prompt()));x[y[10]]=function(c){4===x.readyState&&(w=[].filter.call(x.response[q](".pod h2"),function(a){return"ame:"==a.innerText.slice(-4)})[0].parentElement,(k=w[q]("a")[0])&&"Words only"==k.innerText?(x.open("GET",k.href),x.send()):alert(JSON.parse([].pop.call(x[y[2]][q]("script")).innerHTML.match(/d_0.00\.push\((.+?)\)/)[1]).stringified))};x[s]()
```

The first off the spec is as well the example output
The input `two plus two minus five times five divided by negative zero point five` outputs

[image]

Any other case should get handled fine (now), this is yet pretty ungolfed as is, I just wanted it to get fixed.

```
input: two plus two
output: four

input: twenty-one point five minus one point five
output: twenty

input: one minus two
output: negative one

input: five times five
output: twenty-five

input: twenty-five divided by five
output: five

input: two plus two minus five times five divided by negative zero point five
output: fifty-four

input: one million times one thousand
output: one billion

input: one million times one thousand plus one
output: one billion, one

input: two million plus one million:
output: three million

input: one million plus one million plus one million
output: three million
```

Oh, and if you actually going to test it, it may take a few seconds, as it loads the complete Wolfram Alpha page up to two times.

<sub>Well, there might be a lot to enhance though.</sub>

Comment: I can't deny that this is an amusing answer, though it is too bad it doesn't provide output in the correct format.  Note that the last two examples also have incorrect output.  Of course, there's also the question of how legitimate this answer is... though I didn't explicitly state that you couldn't query some other pre-existing program, I had meant to convey the idea that the translation from English to number, the calculation, and the translation from number to English, should be implemented by the golfer.  It does pass the literal interpretation of the rules though, I'll give it that. :)

Comment: @guest =) I totally, agree with you on that =) It's more of fun answer, beding the rules, than an actual ment codegolf. I'm in the process of fixing the outputs and post a new version. Wolfram Alpha uses images only, took me a while to figure out its stored as a data attribute, b64 encoded.

Comment: @guest, updated it. I hope the outputs are now okay =)

Comment: If you do this in Mathematica you can control the output to give the correct number decimal places and so on (which is what N would do for fractions): [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CowwJ.png)

Comment: +1 for actually being creative with cheating, even though this isn't a [tag:popularity-contest].

Comment: Way too late, but this is against the standard loopholes now

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 982

```
from re import*
S=split
U=sub
a=S(' ',U('_','teen ','zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thir_four_fif_six_seven_eigh_nine_')+U('_','ty ','twen_thir_for_fif_six_seven_eigh_nine_'))
b=range(20)+range(20,99,10)
d=dict(zip(a,b))
D=dict(zip(b,a))
p='point'
v='negative'
def f(s):
 s=S('[ -]',s);n=0.;m=10**(p in s and(s.index(p)-len(s)))
 for x in s[::-1]:m*=10*(m<1)+100*('hu'in x)+1e3*('ho'in x)+1e6*('m'in x)or 1;n+=(x in d)and m*d[x]
 return n-2*n*(v in s)
def F(n):
 l=[v]*(n<0);x=abs(n)
 for i in(9,6,3,0):z=int(x/10**i);h=z%100;g=(z>99)*[D[z/100],'hundred']+(h>0)*[h in D and D[h]or D[h-z%10]+'-'+D[z%10]];l+=g and g+[[],['thousand'],['million'],['billion']][i/3];x%=10**i
 l+=[c=='.'and p or D[int(c)]for c in'%.2g'%x][n**2>=1:];return' '.join(l)
c=lambda n,l:c(eval(`n`+l[0]+`f(l[1])`),l[2:])if l else n
i=S(' (?=. )|(?<= .) ',U('di.*?y','/',U('times','*',U('minus','-',U('plus','+',raw_input())))))
try:print F(c(f(i[0]),i[1:]))
except:print'E'
```

I think it works as it should according to the specs, but there are probably a few more bugs. It might act weirdly for input >= one billion or any unexpected words that it interprets incorrectly.

Here's a slightly more readable version with a few changes:

```
import re
words = re.split(' ', re.sub('_', 'teen ', 'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thir_four_fif_six_seven_eigh_nine_') + re.sub('_', 'ty ', 'twen_thir_for_fif_six_seven_eigh_nine_'))
values = range(20) + range(20, 99, 10)
d = dict(zip(words, values))
D = dict(zip(values, words))

def str_to_num(s):
    s = re.split('[ -]', s)
    n = 0.0
    multiplier = 10 ** ('point' in s and (s.index('point') - len(s)))

    for word in s[::-1]:
        multiplier *= 10 * (multiplier < 1) + 100 * ('hundred' == word) + 1e3 * ('thousand' == word) + 1e6 * ('million' == word) or 1
        n += (word in d) and multiplier * d[word]

    return n - 2 * n * ('negative' in s)


three_digit_num_to_str = lambda n: (n > 99) * [D[n / 100], 'hundred'] + (n % 100 > 0) * [n % 100 in D and D[n % 100] or D[n % 100 - n % 10] + '-' + D[n % 10]]

def num_to_str(n):
    word_list = ['negative'] * (n < 0)
    x = abs(n)

    for i in (9, 6, 3, 0):
        three_digit_str = three_digit_num_to_str(int(x / 10 ** i))
        if three_digit_str:
            word_list += three_digit_str + [[], ['thousand'], ['million'], ['billion']][i / 3]

        x %= 10 ** i

    word_list += [char == '.' and 'point' or D[int(char)] for char in '%.2g' % x][n ** 2 >= 1:]
    return ' '.join(word_list)

calculate = lambda n, l: calculate(eval(str(n) + l[0] + str(str_to_num(l[1]))), l[2:]) if l else n

i = re.split(' (?=. )|(?<= .) ', re.sub('di.*?y', '/', re.sub('times', '*', re.sub('minus', '-', re.sub('plus', '+', raw_input())))))

try:
    print num_to_str(calculate(str_to_num(i[0]), i[1:]))
except:
    print 'E'
```

Answer (score 1):

There we go.  Golfing the version before broke it, but now we're back online.  I'm positive it can be further golfed.  I'll work on it more tomorrow.  It was hard enough to get it working properly WITHOUT golfing it, though, and my eyes are tired of staring at it.  Haha

## Java - 3220

```
import java.util.*;class a{int D=0,i,l,j;static boolean T=true,F=false;enum O{A("plus"),S("minus"),M("times"),D(""),P("point");String t;O(String u){t=u;}double p(double f,double s){if(this==A)f+=s;if(this==S)f-=s;if(this==M)f*=s;if(this==D)f/=s;return f;}static O f(String s){O r=null;for(O o:values())if(s.equals(o.t))r=o;return r;}}enum N{A("zero",0,F),B("one",1,F),C("two",2,F),D("three",3,F),E("four",4,F),AG("five",5,F),G("six",6,F),H("seven",7,F),I("eight",8,F),J("nine",9,F),K("ten",10,F),L("eleven",11,F),M("twelve",12,F),N("thirteen",13,F),O("fourteen",14,F),P("fifteen",15,F),Q("sixteen",16,F),R("seventeen",17,F),S("eighteen",18,F),AH("nineteen",19,F),U("twenty",20,F),V("thirty",30,F),W("forty",40,F),X("fifty",50,F),Y("sixty",60,F),Z("seventy",70,F),AA("eighty",80,F),AB("ninety",90,F),AC("hundred",100,T),AD("thousand",1000,T),AE("million",1000000,T),AF("billion",1000000000,T);String t;double v;boolean q;N(String u,int w,boolean r){t=u;v=w;q=r;}static N f(String s){N r=null;for(N n:values())if(s.equals(n.t))r=n;return r;}static N f(char s){return d(q(""+s));}static N d(double v){N r=null;for(N n:values())if(v==n.v)r=n;return r;}static String c(double n){return d(n).t;}}public static void main(String[]a){new a();}a(){while(T){try{List p=p(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()),t=new ArrayList();double d=0;for(j=0;j<p.size();j++){Object o=p.get(j);if(o(o)){if((O)o==O.P){t.add((d(t.get(t.size()-1))+((d=d(p.get(j+1)))<10?d*=100:d<100?d*=10:d)/1000));t.remove(t.size()-2);j++;}else t.add(o);}else {N n=N.d(d(o));if(n!=null&&n.q){t.add((d(o))*d(t.get(t.size()-1)));t.remove(t.size()-2);}else t.add(o);}}double r=d(t.get(0));for(j=1;j<t.size();j++){Object c=t.get(j),l=t.get(j-1);if(o(c))continue;if(c instanceof Double&&l instanceof Double)r+=d(c);else r=((O)t.get(j-1)).p(r,d(t.get(j)));}System.out.println(p(r));}catch(Exception e){System.out.println("E");}}}List p(String s) {List r=new ArrayList();Scanner i=new Scanner(s);while(i.hasNext()){String c=i.next();if(c.equals("divided")){r.add(O.D);i.next();}else if(c.indexOf("-")!=-1){String[] num=c.split("-");r.add(N.f(num[0]).v+N.f(num[1]).v);}else{Object o=N.f(c);r.add(o!=null?((N)o).v:O.f(c));}}return r;}String p(double n){String a=String.valueOf(n),w,d=null,b="";l=a.indexOf(".");if(l!=-1){w=a.substring(0,l);d=a.substring(l+1);}else w=a;if(d.equals("0"))d=null;D=0;while(w.length()%3!=0)w=" "+w;for(i=w.length();i>0;i-=3,D++)b=w(w.substring(i-3,i))+b;return b+d(d);}String w(String w) {if(w==null)return "";w=w.trim();String b="";l=w.length();if(l>1&&w.charAt(l-2)!='0'){if(w.charAt(l-2)=='1')b=N.d(q(w.substring(l-2))).t;else b+=N.d(q(w.charAt(l-2)+"0")).t+"-"+N.f(w.charAt(l-1)).t;}for(j=(b.equals("")?l-1:l-3);j>-1;j--){N n=N.f(w.charAt(j));if(n==N.A)continue;if(j==l-1)b=n.t;else if(j==l-2)b=N.f(n.t+"0")+"-"+b;else if(j==l-3)b=n.t+" hundred "+b;}if(!b.trim().equals("")){if(D==1)b+=" thousand ";if(D==2)b+=" million ";if(D==3)b+=" billion ";}return b;}String d(String d) {if(d==null)return"";if(d.length()>3)d=d.substring(0,3);String b = " point ";for(char n:d.toCharArray())b+=N.f(n).t+" ";return b;}boolean o(Object o){return o instanceof O;}Double d(Object o){return (Double)o;}static double q(String s){return Double.parseDouble(s);}}
```

**With line breaks and tabs**

```
import java.util.*;

class a{

    int D=0,i,l,j;
    static boolean T=true,F=false;

    enum O{
        A("plus"),
        S("minus"),
        M("times"),
        D(""),
        P("point");

        String t;       
        O(String u){
            t=u;
        }

        double p(double f,double s){
            if(this==A)f+=s;
            if(this==S)f-=s;
            if(this==M)f*=s;
            if(this==D)f/=s;
            return f;
        }

        static O f(String s){
            O r=null;
            for(O o:values())if(s.equals(o.t))r=o;
            return r;
        }
    }

    enum N{
        A("zero",0,F),
        B("one",1,F),
        C("two",2,F),
        D("three",3,F),
        E("four",4,F),
        AG("five",5,F),
        G("six",6,F),
        H("seven",7,F),
        I("eight",8,F),
        J("nine",9,F),
        K("ten",10,F),
        L("eleven",11,F),
        M("twelve",12,F),
        N("thirteen",13,F),
        O("fourteen",14,F),
        P("fifteen",15,F),
        Q("sixteen",16,F),
        R("seventeen",17,F),
        S("eighteen",18,F),
        AH("nineteen",19,F),
        U("twenty",20,F),
        V("thirty",30,F),
        W("forty",40,F),
        X("fifty",50,F),
        Y("sixty",60,F),
        Z("seventy",70,F),
        AA("eighty",80,F),
        AB("ninety",90,F),
        AC("hundred",100,T),
        AD("thousand",1000,T),
        AE("million",1000000,T),
        AF("billion",1000000000,T);

        String t;
        double v;
        boolean q;

        N(String u,int w,boolean r){
            t=u;
            v=w;
            q=r;
        }

        static N f(String s){
            N r=null;
            for(N n:values())if(s.equals(n.t))r=n;
            return r;
        }

        static N f(char s){
            return d(q(""+s));
        }

        static N d(double v){
            N r=null;
            for(N n:values())if(v==n.v)r=n;
            return r;
        }

        static String c(double n){
            return d(n).t;
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[]a){
        new a();
    }


    a(){
        while(T){
            try{
                List p=p(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()),t=new ArrayList();
                double d=0;
                for(j=0;j<p.size();j++){
                    Object o=p.get(j);
                    if(o(o)){
                        if((O)o==O.P){
                            t.add((d(t.get(t.size()-1))+((d=d(p.get(j+1)))<10?d*=100:d<100?d*=10:d)/1000));
                            t.remove(t.size()-2);
                            j++;
                        }
                        else t.add(o);
                    }
                    else {
                        N n=N.d(d(o));
                        if(n!=null&&n.q){
                            t.add((d(o))*d(t.get(t.size()-1)));
                            t.remove(t.size()-2);
                        }
                        else t.add(o);
                    }
                }

                double r=d(t.get(0));
                for(j=1;j<t.size();j++){
                    Object c=t.get(j),l=t.get(j-1);
                    if(o(c))continue;
                    if(c instanceof Double&&l instanceof Double)r+=d(c);
                    else r=((O)t.get(j-1)).p(r,d(t.get(j)));
                }

                System.out.println(p(r));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("E");
            }
        }
    }

    List p(String s) {
        List r=new ArrayList();
        Scanner i=new Scanner(s);
        while(i.hasNext()){
            String c=i.next();
            if(c.equals("divided")){
                r.add(O.D);
                i.next();
            }
            else if(c.indexOf("-")!=-1){
                String[] num=c.split("-");
                r.add(N.f(num[0]).v+N.f(num[1]).v);
            }
            else{
                Object o=N.f(c);
                r.add(o!=null?((N)o).v:O.f(c));
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    String p(double n){

        String a=String.valueOf(n),w,d=null,b="";

        l=a.indexOf(".");
        if(l!=-1){
            w=a.substring(0,l);
            d=a.substring(l+1);
        }
        else w=a;

        if(d.equals("0"))d=null;

        D=0;
        while(w.length()%3!=0)w=" "+w;

        for(i=w.length();i>0;i-=3,D++)b=w(w.substring(i-3,i))+b;

        return b+d(d);
    }


    String w(String w) {
        if(w==null)return "";
        w=w.trim();

        String b="";
        l=w.length();

        if(l>1&&w.charAt(l-2)!='0'){
            if(w.charAt(l-2)=='1')b=N.d(q(w.substring(l-2))).t;
            else b+=N.d(q(w.charAt(l-2)+"0")).t+"-"+N.f(w.charAt(l-1)).t;
        }

        for(j=(b.equals("")?l-1:l-3);j>-1;j--){
            N n=N.f(w.charAt(j));
            if(n==N.A)continue;
            if(j==l-1)b=n.t;
            else if(j==l-2)b=N.f(n.t+"0")+"-"+b;
            else if(j==l-3)b=n.t+" hundred "+b;
        }

        if(!b.trim().equals("")){
            if(D==1)b+=" thousand ";
            if(D==2)b+=" million ";
            if(D==3)b+=" billion ";
        }

        return b;
    }


    String d(String d) {
        if(d==null)return"";
        if(d.length()>3)d=d.substring(0,3);

        String b = " point ";
        for(char n:d.toCharArray())b+=N.f(n).t+" ";

        return b;
    }

    boolean o(Object o){
        return o instanceof O;
    }

    Double d(Object o){
        return (Double)o;
    }

    static double q(String s){
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }

}
```