# Convert English to a number

Tags: popularity-contest

**Short and sweet description of the challenge:**

Based off the ideas of several other questions on this site, your challenge is to write the most creative code in any program that takes as input a number written out in English and converts it to integer form.

**Really dry, long and thorough specifications:**

- Your program will receive as input an integer in **lowercase** English between `zero` and `nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine` inclusive.
- It must output only the integer form of the number between `0` and `999999` and nothing else (no whitespace).
- The input will **NOT** contain `,` or `and`, as in `one thousand, two hundred` or `five hundred and thirty-two`.
- When the tens and ones places are both nonzero and the tens place is greater than `1`, they will be separated by a HYPHEN-MINUS character `-` instead of a space. Ditto for the ten thousands and thousands places. For example, `six hundred fifty-four thousand three hundred twenty-one`.
- The program may have undefined behavior for any other input.

**Some examples of a well-behaved program:**

`zero` -> `0`
`fifteen` -> `15`
`ninety` -> `90`
`seven hundred four` -> `704`
`sixty-nine thousand four hundred eleven` -> `69411`
`five hundred twenty thousand two` -> `520002`

Comment: This isn't especially creative, nor does it precisely match the specification here, but it might be useful as a starting point: https://github.com/ghewgill/text2num/blob/master/text2num.py

Comment: I could almost post my answer to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12757/4020).

Comment: Why do complicated string parsing? http://pastebin.com/WyXevnxb

Comment: By the way, I saw [an IOCCC entry](http://ioccc.org/2012/kang/kang.c) which is the answer of this question.

Comment: What about things like "four and twenty?"

Comment: @fluffy Assume the program only needs to handle standard American English, so it would be inputted as `twenty-four` rather than `four and twenty`.

Comment: This has been put on hold as off-topic. See the [\[popularity-contest\] tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info) for info on creating a good popularity contest. *A clear specification of the goal that must be achieved. Questions like "do (this) the most creative way" should be avoided. Creativity should be the tool, not the goal.*

Answer (score 93, accepted):

## Applescript

A silly, hacky mash-up that might upset some Cupertino/Mountain View folks, but I *think* its a creative silly, hacky mash-up.

```applescript
set myNumber to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Enter number as text:" buttons {"Continue…"} ¬
    default answer "" default button 1)
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "https://www.google.com"
end tell
delay 5
say "ok google. " & myNumber
delay 2
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Google Chrome"
        set fullURL to value of text field 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "="
display alert item 2 of text items of fullURL
```

Uses OSX text to speech to speak the text number, and google audio search to listen for it and convert it to an integer.

Requirements

- OSX
- Google chrome
- speech-recognition enabled in your google account
- volume turned up to a reasonable level

The delay timings may need to be adjusted depending on your chrome load time and google lookup time.

Example input:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I *think* that might be just a *little* creative... ;)

Comment: Lol, this is cool

Comment: Maybe _too_ creative.

Comment: After one week, your answer is clearly in the lead at 74 votes, so I think that means that.. you win! By the way, mind if I use this code? It would be really useful for a lot of real-world projects I'm working on right now! ;)

Comment: @Abraham Thanks!  You're joking about using this in production code, right?

Answer (score 35):

## Bash, <strike>93</strike> <strike>64</strike> 55 characters*

In the fantastic `bsd-games` package that's available on most Linux operating systems, there's a small command-line toy called `number`. It turns numbers into English text, that is, it does the exact opposite of this question. It really is the exact opposite: all the rules in the question are followed by `number`. It's almost too good to be a coincidence.

```
$ number 42
forty-two.
```

Of course, `number` doesn't answer the question. We want it the other way around. I thought about this for a while, tried string parsing and all that, then realised that I can just call `number` on all 999.999 numbers and see if something matches the input. If so, the first line where it matches has twice the line number I'm looking for (`number` prints a line of dots after every number). Simple as that. So, without further ado, here's the complete code for my entry:

```
seq 0 999999|number -l|awk "/$1/{print (NR-1)/2;exit}"
```

It even short-circuits, so converting "two" is quite fast, and even higher numbers are usually decoded in under a second on my box. Here's an example run:

```
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "zero"
0
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "fifteen"
15
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "ninety" 
90
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "seven hundred four"
704
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "sixty-nine thousand four hundred eleven"
69411
wn@box /tmp> bash unnumber.sh "five hundred twenty thousand two"    
520002
```

Of course, you'll need to have `number` installed for this to work.

---

*: Yes, I know, this is not a `code-golf` challenge, but shortness is pretty much the only discerning quality of my entry, so... :)

Comment: +1.  For me, using `number` in reverse is the most creative thing about this answer.  The golfiness is good too though :)

Comment: This is actually quite creative! I like it!

Answer (score 13):

## Javascript

```javascript
(function parse(input) {
  var pat = "ze/on/tw/th.?r/fo/fi/ix/se/ei/ni/ten/ele".split("/");
  var num = "", last = 0, token = input.replace(/-/g, " ").split(" ");
  for(var i in token) {
    var t = token[i];
    for(var p in pat) if(t.match(RegExp(pat[p])) !== null) num += "+" + p;
    if(t.indexOf("een") >= 0) num += "+10";
    if(t.indexOf("lve") >= 0) num += "+10";
    if(t.indexOf("ty") >= 0) num += "*10";
    if(t.indexOf("dr") >= 0) { last = 100; num += "*100"; }
    if(t.indexOf("us") >= 0) {
      if(last < 1000) num = "(" + num + ")"; last = 0;
      num += "*1000";
    }
  }
  alert(eval(num));
})(prompt());
```

Do you like some `eval()`?

Run this script on your browser's console.

**Edit:** Thanks for the feedback. Bugs fixed (again).

Comment: really nice code ^^

Comment: When you type something like "one hundred sixteen", it'll give 126.

Comment: This program fails for some numbers starting at `twelve` when it returns `23`.

Comment: Fails on `"twenty"`.

Comment: `seven thousand three hundred thirty five` give me `10335`

Comment: @ImmerAllein It will work now.

Answer (score 7):

### Python

Just to get the ball rolling.

```py
import re
table = {'zero':0,'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5,'six':6,'seven':7,'eight':8,'nine':9,
         'ten':10,'eleven':11,'twelve':12,'thirteen':13,'fourteen':14,'fifteen':15,'sixteen':16,'seventeen':17,'eighteen':18,'nineteen':19,
         'twenty':20,'thirty':30,'forty':40,'fifty':50,'sixty':60,'ninety':90}
modifier = {'hundred':100,'thousand':1000}

while True:
    text = raw_input()
    result = 0
    tmp = 0
    last_multiplier = 1
    for word in re.split('[- ]', text):
        multiplier = modifier.get(word, 1)
        if multiplier > last_multiplier:
            result = (result+tmp)*multiplier
            tmp = 0
        else:
            tmp *= multiplier
        if multiplier != 1:
            last_multiplier = multiplier
        tmp += table.get(word,0)
    print result+tmp
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl + CPAN

Why reinvent the wheel, when it has been done already?

```perl
use feature 'say';
use Lingua::EN::Words2Nums;

say words2nums $_ while <>;
```

This program reads English strings from standard input (or from one or more files specified as command line arguments), one per line, and prints out the corresponding numbers to standard output.

I have tested this code using both the sample inputs from the challenge, as well as an exhaustive test suite consisting of the numbers from 0 to 999999 converted to text using the bsd-games `number` utility (thanks, Wander Nauta!), and it correctly parses all of them.  As a bonus, it also understands such inputs as e.g. `minus seven` (−7), `four and twenty` (24), `four score and seven` (87), `one gross` (144), `a baker's dozen` (13), `eleventy-one` (111) and `googol` (10<sup>100</sup>).

(*Note:* In addition to the Perl interpreter itself, this program also requires the CPAN module [Lingua::EN::Words2Nums](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3A%3AEN%3A%3AWords2Nums).  Here are some [instructions for installing CPAN modules](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).  Debian / Ubuntu Linux users may also install this module via the APT package manager as *liblingua-en-words2nums-perl*.)

Answer (score 4):

## Python

A general recursive solution, with validity checking. Could be simplified for the range of numbers required, but here's to showing off I guess:

```python
terms = 'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen'.split()
tee  = 'twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety'.split()
for t in tee:
    terms.append(t)
    for s in terms[1:10]:
        terms.append(t+'-'+s)

terms = dict(zip(terms, range(100)))

modifiers = [('hundred', 100), ('thousand', 1000), ('million', 10**6), ('billion', 10**9)]

def read_num(words):
    if len(words) == 0: return 0
    elif len(words) == 1:
        if words[0] in terms:
            return terms[words[0]]
        else:
            raise ValueError(words[0]+' is not a valid english number.')
    else:
        for word, value in reversed(modifiers):
            if word in words:
                i = words.index(word)
                return read_num(words[:i])*value+read_num(words[i+1:])

    raise ValueError(' '.join(words)+' is not a valid english number.')

while True:
    try:
        print(read_num(input().split()))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

### VBScript 474

This is a fairly routine answer... unfortunately, so routine that @Snack pretty much posted the same process but before me.

```
i=split(REPLACE(REPLACE(inputbox(""),"lve","een"),"tho","k"))
o=split("z on tw th fo fi si se ei ni ten ele")
y=split("red *100) k )*1000 ty *10) een +10)")
z=""
p=0
for t=0 to UBOUND(i)
    s=split(i(t),"-")
    u=ubound(s)
    r=s(0)
    for x=0 to UBOUND(o)    
        IF INSTR(r,o(x)) THEN
            z=z+"+"+CSTR(x)
        END IF
        IF u Then
            IF INSTR(s(1),o(x)) THEN
                z=z+CSTR(x)
            END IF
        END IF
    next
    for m=0 to UBOUND(y)
        IF INSTR(r,y(m))AND u=0 THEN
            z=z+y(m+1)
            p=p+1
        END IF
    next
next
Execute("MSGBOX "+String(p,"(")+z)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

Similar to other recursive solutions I guess, but I took the time to make it clean.

Here is the complete source with all explanations : http://ideone.com/fc8zcB

```
-- Define a type for a parser from a list of tokens to the value they represent.
type NParse = [Token] -> Int    

-- Map of literal tokens (0-9, 11-19 and tens) to their names.
literals = [
        ("zero", 0), ("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4), ("five", 5), ("six", 6), ("seven", 7), ("eight", 8), ("nine", 9),
        ("eleven", 11), ("twelve", 12), ("thirteen", 13), ("fourteen", 14), ("fifteen", 15), ("sixteen", 16), ("seventeen", 17), ("eighteen", 18), ("nineteen", 19),
        ("ten", 10), ("twenty", 20), ("thirty", 30), ("fourty", 40), ("fifty", 50), ("sixty", 60), ("seventy", 70), ("eighty", 80), ("ninety", 90)
    ]

-- Splits the input string into tokens.
-- We do one special transformation: replace dshes by a new token. Such that "fifty-three" becomes "fifty tens three". 
prepare :: String -> [Token]

-- Let's do the easy stuff and just parse literals first. We just have to look them up in the literals map.
-- This is our base parser.
parseL :: NParse
parseL [tok] = case lookup tok literals of 
    Just x -> x

-- We're going to exploit the fact that the input strings have a tree-like structure like so
--                    thousand
--          hundred             hundred
--      ten       ten       ten         ten
--    lit   lit lit  lit   lit  lit    lit  lit
-- And recursively parse that tree until we only have literal values.
--
-- When parsing the tree
--       thousand
--     h1       h2
-- The resulting value is 1000 * h1 + h2.
-- And this works similarly for all levels of the tree.
-- So instead of writing specific parsers for all levels, let's just write a generic one :

{- genParse :: 
    NParse      : the sub parser
    -> Int      : the left part multiplier
    -> Token    : the boundary token 
    -> NParse   : returns a new parser -}   
genParse :: NParse -> Int -> Token -> NParse    
genParse delegate mul tok = newParser where
    newParser [] = 0
    newParser str = case splitAround str tok of
        -- Split around the boundary token, sub-parse the left and right parts, and combine them
        (l,r) -> (delegate l) * mul + (delegate r)  

-- And so here's the result: 
parseNumber :: String -> Int
parseNumber = parseM . prepare
    where   -- Here are all intermediary parsers for each level
    parseT = genParse   parseL  1       "tens"       -- multiplier is irregular, because the fifty in fifty-three is already multiplied by 10
    parseH = genParse   parseT  100     "hundred"
    parseK = genParse   parseH  1000    "thousand"
    parseM = genParse   parseK  1000000 "million" -- For fun :D

test = (parseNumber "five hundred twenty-three thousand six hundred twelve million two thousand one") == 523612002001
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 94

```cl
(write(cdr(assoc(read-line)(loop for i to 999999 collect(cons(format()"~r"i)i)):test #'equalp)))
```

Number to text conversion is built in to CL, but not the other way around. Builds a reverse mapping for the numbers and checks the input on it.