# Convert English to a number without built-ins or libraries

Tags: code-golf, number, kolmogorov-complexity, natural-language, conversion

This challenge is similar to [this other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32381/convert-english-to-a-number), however I made a restriction (see bold text below) that I think would made it much diffent and (I hope) fun either.

## The Challenge

Write a program or a function in any programming language that takes as input the English name of a positive integer `n` not exceeding `100` and returns `n` as an integer.

[Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden and ***you cannot use any built-in function, external tool, or library that already does this job***.

Shortest source code in bytes wins.

## Test

Here all the `input->output` cases:

```
one              -> 1
two              -> 2
three            -> 3
four             -> 4
five             -> 5
six              -> 6
seven            -> 7
eight            -> 8
nine             -> 9
ten              -> 10
eleven           -> 11
twelve           -> 12
thirteen         -> 13
fourteen         -> 14
fifteen          -> 15
sixteen          -> 16
seventeen        -> 17
eighteen         -> 18
nineteen         -> 19
twenty           -> 20
twenty-one       -> 21
twenty-two       -> 22
twenty-three     -> 23
twenty-four      -> 24
twenty-five      -> 25
twenty-six       -> 26
twenty-seven     -> 27
twenty-eight     -> 28
twenty-nine      -> 29
thirty           -> 30
thirty-one       -> 31
thirty-two       -> 32
thirty-three     -> 33
thirty-four      -> 34
thirty-five      -> 35
thirty-six       -> 36
thirty-seven     -> 37
thirty-eight     -> 38
thirty-nine      -> 39
forty            -> 40
forty-one        -> 41
forty-two        -> 42
forty-three      -> 43
forty-four       -> 44
forty-five       -> 45
forty-six        -> 46
forty-seven      -> 47
forty-eight      -> 48
forty-nine       -> 49
fifty            -> 50
fifty-one        -> 51
fifty-two        -> 52
fifty-three      -> 53
fifty-four       -> 54
fifty-five       -> 55
fifty-six        -> 56
fifty-seven      -> 57
fifty-eight      -> 58
fifty-nine       -> 59
sixty            -> 60
sixty-one        -> 61
sixty-two        -> 62
sixty-three      -> 63
sixty-four       -> 64
sixty-five       -> 65
sixty-six        -> 66
sixty-seven      -> 67
sixty-eight      -> 68
sixty-nine       -> 69
seventy          -> 70
seventy-one      -> 71
seventy-two      -> 72
seventy-three    -> 73
seventy-four     -> 74
seventy-five     -> 75
seventy-six      -> 76
seventy-seven    -> 77
seventy-eight    -> 78
seventy-nine     -> 79
eighty           -> 80
eighty-one       -> 81
eighty-two       -> 82
eighty-three     -> 83
eighty-four      -> 84
eighty-five      -> 85
eighty-six       -> 86
eighty-seven     -> 87
eighty-eight     -> 88
eighty-nine      -> 89
ninety           -> 90
ninety-one       -> 91
ninety-two       -> 92
ninety-three     -> 93
ninety-four      -> 94
ninety-five      -> 95
ninety-six       -> 96
ninety-seven     -> 97
ninety-eight     -> 98
ninety-nine      -> 99
one hundred      -> 100
```

Comment: What about a built-in that does half the job, for example finding the unicode name of a codepoint.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills No, it is not fine.

Answer (score 22):

## C, 160 bytes

```c
g(char*s){char i=1,r=0,*p="k^[#>Pcx.yI<7CZpVgmH:o]sYK$2";for(;*s^'-'&&*s;r+=*s++|9);r=r%45+77;for(;*p!=r;p++,i++);return((*s^'-')?0:g(s+1))+(i<21?i:10*(i-18));}
```

## Test it

```c
int main ()
{
    char* w[] = {"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "twenty-one", "twenty-two", "twenty-three", "twenty-four", "twenty-five", "twenty-six", "twenty-seven", "twenty-eight", "twenty-nine", "thirty", "thirty-one", "thirty-two", "thirty-three", "thirty-four", "thirty-five", "thirty-six", "thirty-seven", "thirty-eight", "thirty-nine", "forty", "forty-one", "forty-two", "forty-three", "forty-four", "forty-five", "forty-six", "forty-seven", "forty-eight", "forty-nine", "fifty", "fifty-one", "fifty-two", "fifty-three", "fifty-four", "fifty-five", "fifty-six", "fifty-seven", "fifty-eight", "fifty-nine", "sixty", "sixty-one", "sixty-two", "sixty-three", "sixty-four", "sixty-five", "sixty-six", "sixty-seven", "sixty-eight", "sixty-nine", "seventy", "seventy-one", "seventy-two", "seventy-three", "seventy-four", "seventy-five", "seventy-six", "seventy-seven", "seventy-eight", "seventy-nine", "eighty", "eighty-one", "eighty-two", "eighty-three", "eighty-four", "eighty-five", "eighty-six", "eighty-seven", "eighty-eight", "eighty-nine", "ninety", "ninety-one", "ninety-two", "ninety-three", "ninety-four", "ninety-five", "ninety-six", "ninety-seven", "ninety-eight", "ninety-nine", "one hundred"};

    int n;
    for (n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
        printf ("%s -> %d\n", w[n], g(w[n]));
        if (n != g(w[n]))
        {
            printf ("Error at n = %d", n);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## How it works

After some attempts, I found a function that maps the "exceptional" numbers `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, `five`, `six`, `seven`, `eight`, `nine`, `ten`, `eleven`, `twelve`, `thirteen`, `fourteen`, `fifteen`, `sixteen`, `seventeen`, `eighteen`, `nineteen`, `twenty`, `thirty`, `forty`, `fifty`, `sixty`, `seventy`, `eighty`, `ninety`, `one hundred`, to the printable ASCII characters `k`, `.`, `[`, `<`, `*`, , `c`, `K`, `w`, `y`, `e`, `(`, `S`, `_`, `-`, `C`, `)`, `7`, `=`, `4`, `&`, `o`, `]`, `s`, `Y`, `g`, `m`, `N`, respectively.

This function is:

```c
char hash (char* s)
{
    char r = 0;

    while (*s)
    {
        r += *s|9;
        s++;
    }

    return r%45+77;
}
```

The golfed program computes the `hash` function of the input until it reaches the end of the string or the character `-`. Then it searches the hash in the string `k.[<* cKwye(S_-C)7=4&o]sYgmN` and determines the corresponding number. If the end of the input string was reached the number is returned, if instead a `-` was reached, then it is returned the number plus the result of the golfed program applied to the rest of the input string.

Comment: I'm thinking, if there were a golfing version of C, it might actually beat languages like CJam Pyth Japt etc...

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>175</s> <s>166</s> <s>163</s> <s>156</s> <s>153</s> 147 bytes

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
a=>+a.replace(/.+te|.*el|y$/,x=>x[1]?'on-'+x:'-d').split(/ |-|dr/).map(x=>"un|d,on|le,w,th,fo,f,x,s,h,i,".split`,`.findIndex(y=>x.match(y))).join``
```

Verify it here:

```js
f=a=>+a.replace(/.+te|.*el|y$/,x=>x[1]?'on-'+x:'-d').split(/ |-|dr/).map(x=>"un|d,on|le,w,th,fo,f,x,s,h,i,".split`,`.findIndex(y=>x.match(y))).join``;

document.body.innerHTML="<pre>"+["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty","twenty-one","twenty-two","twenty-three","twenty-four","twenty-five","twenty-six","twenty-seven","twenty-eight","twenty-nine","thirty","thirty-one","thirty-two","thirty-three","thirty-four","thirty-five","thirty-six","thirty-seven","thirty-eight","thirty-nine","forty","forty-one","forty-two","forty-three","forty-four","forty-five","forty-six","forty-seven","forty-eight","forty-nine","fifty","fifty-one","fifty-two","fifty-three","fifty-four","fifty-five","fifty-six","fifty-seven","fifty-eight","fifty-nine","sixty","sixty-one","sixty-two","sixty-three","sixty-four","sixty-five","sixty-six","sixty-seven","sixty-eight","sixty-nine","seventy","seventy-one","seventy-two","seventy-three","seventy-four","seventy-five","seventy-six","seventy-seven","seventy-eight","seventy-nine","eighty","eighty-one","eighty-two","eighty-three","eighty-four","eighty-five","eighty-six","eighty-seven","eighty-eight","eighty-nine","ninety","ninety-one","ninety-two","ninety-three","ninety-four","ninety-five","ninety-six","ninety-seven","ninety-eight","ninety-nine","one hundred"].map((x,y)=>'f("'+x+'") === '+f(x)+"? "+(f(x)===y+1)).join("<br>")+"</pre>"
```

#### How it works

The basic idea is to split each number into its digit-words, then map each word to the corresponding digit. *Almost* all of the words are set up to be matched properly with a simple regex, but there are a few anomalies:

- `eleven` through `nineteen`: if the word contains an `el`, or a `te` in the middle (to avoid `ten`), we add a `on-` to the beginning, changing these to `on-eleven` through `on-nineteen`.
- `twenty`, `thirty`, etc.: replacing a trailing `y` with `-d` changes these to `twent-d`, `thirt-d`, etc.

Now we split at hyphens, spaces, and `dr`s. This splits everything from 11 to 99 into its corresponding digit-words, and `"one hundred"` into `[one,hun,ed]`. Then we map each of these words through an array of regexes, and keep the index of the one that matches first.

```
0: /un|d/ - This matches the "hun" and "ed" in 100, as well as the "d" we placed on the end of 20, 30, etc.
1: /on|le/ - Matches "one" and the "on" we placed on the beginning of 11 through 19, along with "eleven".
2: /w/ - Matches "two", "twelve", and "twenty".
3: /th/ - Matches "three" and "thirty".
4: /fo/ - Matches "four" and "forty".
5: /f/ - "five" and "fifty" are the only words by now that contain an "f".
6: /x/ - "six" and "sixty" are the only words that contain an "x".
7: /s/ - "seven" and "seventy" are the only words by now that contain an "s".
8: /h/ - "eight" and "eighty" are the only words by now that contain an "h".
9: /i/ - "nine" and "ninety" are the only words by now that contain an "i".
10: /<empty>/ - "ten" is the only word left, but it still has to be matched.
```

By now, each and every input will be the array of the proper digits. All we have to do is join them with ``` join`` ``` , convert to a number with unary `+`, and we're done.

Comment: Please, explain.

Comment: @Bob Sure, explanation added.

Comment: Doesn't `.findIndex(y=>x.match(y))` work?

Comment: @Neil I didn't realize that would, but it does, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can alias `replace`.

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ Exactly the same length :( `a=>+a[r="replace"](/(.+)te/,'on-$1')[r](/y$/,'-d')...`

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ Fortunately, combining the two replaces saved three bytes!

Answer (score 6):

## sh + coreutils, 112 bytes

Can be run on all testcases at once, one per line.

```
sed -r "`awk '$0="s/"$0"/+"NR"/g"'<<<"on
tw
th
fo
fi
si
se
ei
ni
te|lv
el"`
s/ /y0/
s/y/*10/
s/^\+|[a-z-]//g"|bc
```

### Explanation

The backticked `awk` evaluates to the `sed` script

```
s/on/+1/g       # one, one hundred
s/tw/+2/g       # two, twelve, twenty
s/th/+3/g       # three, thirteen, thirty
s/fo/+4/g       # ...
s/fi/+5/g
s/si/+6/g
s/se/+7/g
s/ei/+8/g
s/ni/+9/g
s/te|lv/+10/g   # ten, -teen, twelve
s/el/+11/g      # eleven
```

which transforms parts of numbers into their numeric representation.

```
fife            ->    +5ve
ten             ->    +10n
eleven          ->    +11even
twelve          ->    +2e+10e
sixteen         ->    +6x+10en
thirty-seven    ->    +3irty-+7ven
forty-four      ->    +4rty-+4ur
eighty          ->    +8ghty
one hundred     ->    +1e hundred
```

The additional lines of the sed script

```
s/ /y0/
s/y/*10/
```

take care of `-ty`s and `one hundred`.

```
+3irty-+7ven    ->    +3irt*10-+7ven
+4rty-+4ur      ->    +4rt*10-+4ur
+8ghty          ->    +8ght*10
+1e hundred     ->    +1ey0hundred      ->    +1e*100hundred
```

Finally, remove leading `+`s and everything that is not `+`, `*` or a digit.

```
s/^\+|[a-z-]//g"
```

Only math expressions remain

```
fife            ->    5
sixteen         ->    6+10
forty-four      ->    4*10+4
eighty          ->    8*10
one hundred     ->    1*100
```

and can be piped into `bc`.

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, <strike>79</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>75</strike> 68 bytes

Thank @ETHproductions for 7 bytes.

```
?}"hu"z100sm*+hxc."ewEÐ¡Bu­["2<d2?|}"een"d}"lv"dTZ?}"ty"dT1cz\-
```

Basically first checks the corner case of 100, then uses an array of the first two letters of the numbers 0 to 11 to determine the semantics of the input and modify the value according to suffix ("-ty" and "-teen"; "lv" in 12 is another corner case). First splits input into a list of words, then map each one to a value, and sum them up.

In pythonic pseudocode:

```
                           z = input()    # raw, unevaluated
                           Z = 0
                           T = 10
?}"hu"z                    if "hu" in z:  # checks if input is 100
  100                        print(100)
                           else:
sm                           sum(map( lambda d: # evaluates each word, then sum
  *                            multiply(
   +hxc."ewEÐ¡Bu­["2<d2           plusOne(chop("ontwth...niteel",2).index(d[:2])) + \
                                 # chops string into ["on","tw",..."el"]
                                 # ."ewEÐ¡Bu­[" is a packed string
     ?|}"een"d}"lv"dTZ               (T if "een" in d or "lv" in d else Z),
                                     # add 10 for numbers from 12 to 19
   ?}"ty"dT1                     T if "ty" in d else 1),  # times 10 if "-ty"
  cz\-                         z.split("-"))  # splits input into words
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%7D%22hu%22z100sm%2a%2Bhxc.%22ew%18E%C3%90%01%C2%A1%02B%1Bu%C2%AD%5B%C2%91%222%3Cd2%3F%7C%7D%22een%22d%7D%22lv%22dTZ%3F%7D%22ty%22dT1cz%5C-&input=hundred&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=one%0Atwo%0Athree%0Afour%0Afive%0Asix%0Aseven%0Aeight%0Anine%0Aten%0Aeleven%0Atwelve%0Athirteen%0Afourteen%0Afifteen%0Asixteen%0Aseventeen%0Aeighteen%0Anineteen%0Atwenty%0Atwenty-one%0Atwenty-two%0Atwenty-three%0Atwenty-four%0Atwenty-five%0Atwenty-six%0Atwenty-seven%0Atwenty-eight%0Atwenty-nine%0Athirty%0Athirty-one%0Athirty-two%0Athirty-three%0Athirty-four%0Athirty-five%0Athirty-six%0Athirty-seven%0Athirty-eight%0Athirty-nine%0Aforty%0Aforty-one%0Aforty-two%0Aforty-three%0Aforty-four%0Aforty-five%0Aforty-six%0Aforty-seven%0Aforty-eight%0Aforty-nine%0Afifty%0Afifty-one%0Afifty-two%0Afifty-three%0Afifty-four%0Afifty-five%0Afifty-six%0Afifty-seven%0Afifty-eight%0Afifty-nine%0Asixty%0Asixty-one%0Asixty-two%0Asixty-three%0Asixty-four%0Asixty-five%0Asixty-six%0Asixty-seven%0Asixty-eight%0Asixty-nine%0Aseventy%0Aseventy-one%0Aseventy-two%0Aseventy-three%0Aseventy-four%0Aseventy-five%0Aseventy-six%0Aseventy-seven%0Aseventy-eight%0Aseventy-nine%0Aeighty%0Aeighty-one%0Aeighty-two%0Aeighty-three%0Aeighty-four%0Aeighty-five%0Aeighty-six%0Aeighty-seven%0Aeighty-eight%0Aeighty-nine%0Aninety%0Aninety-one%0Aninety-two%0Aninety-three%0Aninety-four%0Aninety-five%0Aninety-six%0Aninety-seven%0Aninety-eight%0Aninety-nine%0Aone+hundred&debug=0)

---

### Python 3, 218 bytes

```
z=input()
if "hu" in z:print(100);exit()
print(sum(map(lambda d:([0,"on","tw","th","fo","fi","si","se","ei","ni","te","el"].index(d[:2])+(10 if "een" in d or "lv" in d else 0))*(10 if "ty" in d else 1),z.split("-"))))
```

Basically identical to the Pyth answer.

---

Off-topic:

I just discovered a meaningful version of the answer to life, the universe and everything: it's tea-thirsty twigs. Wow, twigs that yearn for tea! I'm not sure how many other answers do this, but for my answer if the input is "tea-thirsty-twigs" the output is 42.

Comment: I believe you can save seven bytes by using a [packed string](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2B%2B\.N%2B%2BhSzeSzCi-RChSzCMz-hCeSzChSzN&input=ontwthfofisiseeiniteel&debug=0). Copy the output and put it in place of `"ontwthfofisiseeiniteel"` in this program.

Comment: @ETHproductions Wow, thanks! The last time I checked, there was still "ze" at the head of the string, and packing couldn't work. I didn't check once more after I golfed it out. Again, thanks xD

Comment: @ETHproductions yes I actually did, it's under the pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <del>252</del> 231 bytes

```
let l=words;k=l"six seven eight nine";w=l"one two three four five"++k++l"ten eleven twelve"++((++"teen")<$>l"thir four fif"++k)++[n++"ty"++s|n<-l"twen thir for fif"++k,s<-"":['-':x|x<-take 9w]]in maybe 100id.flip lookup(zip w[1..])
```

This creates a list of all English number names from "one" to "ninety-nine" and then looks the index of the input up. If it doesn't exist, we're in the edge case "one hundred", so it returns `100`, otherwise it's going to return the index.

#### Ungolfed

```
-- k in the golfed variant
common = words "six seven eight nine" 

-- w in the golfed variant
numbers = words "one two three four five" ++ common
       ++ words "ten eleven twelve" ++ [p ++ "teen" | p <- words "thir four fif" ++ common]
       ++ [p ++ "ty" ++ s| p <- words "twen thir for fif" ++ common
                         , s <- "" : map ('-':) (take 9 numbers)]

-- part of the expression in the golfed variant
convert :: String -> Int
convert s = maybe 100 id $ lookup s $ zip numbers [1..]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>365</s> <s>361</s> <s>310</s> 303 characters

### Golfed

```
def f(a):
 y=0
 for i in a.split("-"):
  x="one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir;four;fif;six;seven;eigh;nine;twenty,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty,seventy,eighty,ninety,one hundred".replace(";","teen,").split(",").index(i)
  y+=x+1 if x<20 else range(30,110,10)[x-20]
 return y
```

### Ungolfed

```
 def nameToNumber (numberName):
    names = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen",
             "fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty","thirty","forty","fifty",
             "sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety","one hundred"]
    numbers = range(30, 110, 10)
    number = 0
    for n in numberName.split("-"):
        x = names.index(n)
        number += x + 1 if x < 20 else numbers[x - 20]
    return number
```

Comment: 45 characters shorter: `n="one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty,seventy,eighty,ninety,one hundred".split(",")` But as I see, should work without assigning it to variable n, just call `.index()` directly on it.

Comment: 7 characters shorter: `"one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thir;four;fif;six;seven;eigh;nine;twenty,thirty,forty,fifty,sixty,seventy,eighty,ninety,one hundred".replace(";","teen,").split(",")`.

Comment: The StackExchange site engine has an irritating habit: it inserts invisible characters (U200C Zero Width Non-Joiner and U200B Zero Width Space) into the code posted in comments. You copy-pasted them too. I edited your post to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 275 characters

```
def x(n):a='one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve'.split();t='twen thir four fif six seven eigh nine'.split();b=[i+'teen'for i in t[1:]];c=[i+'ty'for i in t];return(a+b+[i+j for i in c for j in ['']+['-'+k for k in a[:9]]]+['one hundred']).index(n)+1
```

It simple builds a list of every number and finds the index.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 82 bytes

```
+Ur`(.+)¿``¿-$1` r"y$""-d" q$/ |-|dr/$ £`un|Üaiwo|ØÏ¿ifoifix¿iÊ¿¿e¿iv`qi b_XfZ}Ãq
```

Each `¿` represents an unprintable char. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=K1VyYCguKymSYGCNLSQxYCByInkkIiItZCIgcSQvIHwtfGRyLyQgo2B1bnzcYWl3b3zYz5BpZm9pZml4iWnKgopliGl2YHFpIGJfWGZafcNx&input=InNldmVudHktdHdvIg==)

Based on my JS answer. Subtract one byte if the output doesn't need to be an integer, since it would appear exactly the same as a string.

#### How it works

```
+Ur`(.+)¿` `¿-$1`  r"y$""-d" q/ |-|dr/ £  `un|Üaiwo|ØÏ¿ifoifix¿iÊ¿¿e¿iv`          qi b_ XfZ}Ã q
+Ur"(.+)te""on-$1" r"y$""-d" q/ |-|dr/ mX{"un|dioniwo|wenithifoifixisihineiteiniv"qi bZ{XfZ}} q

Ur"(.+)te""on-$1" // Replace "thirteen", "fourteen", etc. with "on-thiren", "on-fouren", etc.
r"y$""-d"         // Replace "twenty", "thirty", etc. with "twent-d", "thirt-d", etc.
q/ |-|dr/         // Split at occurances of a space, hyphen, or "dr". By now,
                  // "one", "thirteen", "twenty", "sixty-six", "one hundred" will have become:
                  // "one", "on" "thiren", "twent" "d", "sixty" "six", "one" "hun" "ed"
mX         }      // Map each item X in the resulting array to:
"..."qi           //  Take this string, split at "i"s,
b_XfZ}            //  and find the first item Z where X.match(RegExp(Z)) is not null.
                  //  See my JS answer to learn exactly how this works.
                  // Our previous example is now
                  // "1", "1" "3", "2" "0", "6" "6", "1" "0" "0"
+              q  // Join and convert to integer.
                  // 1, 13, 20, 66, 100
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>214</s> 199 bytes

As always: turns out this is too long to compete, but now that I'm done it'd be a waste not to post this.

Perhaps there's an obvious way to golf this further that I've overlooked?

```
e=s=>s.slice(-1)=='d'?100:'  ontwthfofisiseeinite'.indexOf(s.slice(0,2))/2;f=s=>([t,u]=s.split('-'),~s.indexOf`le`?11:~s.indexOf`lv`?12:e(t)+(t.slice(-3)=='een')*10+''+(u?e(u):t.slice(-1)=='y'?0:''))
```

[JSFiddle for test cases](https://jsfiddle.net/7n10vn7j/1/)

Comment: How about changing `f` to `f=s=>([t,u]=s.split('-'),~s.indexOf('le')?11:~s.indexOf('lv')?12:e(t)+(t.slice(-3)=='een')*10+''+(u?e(u):t.slice(-1)=='y'?0:''))`? Also, a single string argument can be passed to a function like so: ``s.indexOf`lv` ``

Comment: @ETHproductions That's great, thanks! I didn't know JS had a comma operator, and the shorthand for string passing is really useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 158 bytes

```
@s=split/(\d+)/,'te1ten0l1le1on1tw2th3fo4fi5si6se7ei8ni9d00';foreach(split'-',$n=$ARGV[0]){for($i=0;$i<$#s;$i+=2){m/$s[$i]/&&print$s[$i+1]}}$n=~/ty$/&&print 0
```

Runs from the command line. `one hundred` must be entered as `"one hundred"` to stop it being interpreted as two inputs.