# Convert a string of digits from words to an integer

Tags: code-golf, string, number, conversion

Convert a string containing digits as words into an integer, ignoring leading zeros.

## Examples

- `"four two"` -> `42`.
- `"zero zero zero one"` -> `1`.

## Assumptions

Submissions can assume that:

1. The input string is comprised of space-separated digit words.
2. All words are valid (in the range "zero".."nine") and lowercase. Behaviour for empty input is undefined.
3. The input string always represents an unsigned number within the range of `int` and is never an empty string.

## Scoring

Answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are a couple of things that we usually expect from questions that are missing here.  The most important would be an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria) which all challenges must have.

Comment: Aside from that this question is very sparse on specification.  You should specify exactly what is required of submissions without ambiguity.  One sentence and an example just isn't up to our clarity standards for challenges.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic the `code-golf` tag is enough?

Comment: On top of what has been said already, we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) where users can post their challenges before posting them to main. That way you will miss less information when making posts. If you look at other recent posts on the site with a reasonably positive reception I think you will see that both your question and solution aren't quite in line with what we do here.

Comment: To handle the scoring criterion it would be the absolute minimum.  You really should put a sentence in the body of the question though.  E.g. "Answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better".  There is technically more than one way to score [tag:code-golf], but bytes is overwhelmingly the most popular.

Comment: What behavior is expected on leading zeros for example should `zero zero one` output  `001`, `1`, or are both allowed?  Also what should be done with the empty string?  Does it count as `0` or is it not a valid input?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, I'd like to point out that the `range "zero".."nine"` is not fully specified.

Comment: Annoyingly, the builtin `Interpreter@"SemanticNumber"` does exactly this in Mathematica—except that it fails on strings starting with `zero zero `.

Comment: I have troubles parsing the title. Shouldn't it be written in the usual way, "I ... the source code, you .. the input!" ?

Comment: What's unclear here? Why the VTCs? The only potential issue I see is the one raised by @UnrelatedString above.

Comment: Can we assume the input is all uppercase, rather than all lowercase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert English to a number without built-ins or libraries](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71681/convert-english-to-a-number-without-built-ins-or-libraries)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire it's a different challenge to that one - this one is only the digits rather than the ordinal number in English (i.e. "four two" here "fourty two" there) this makes quite a difference.

Answer (score 24):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

```php
foreach(explode(' ',$argn)as$w)$n.='793251_8640'[crc32($w)%20%11];echo+$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1LCsIwFAD3PUUoKUnwQz9@ieLOS6hISJ9GkPdCklLx8Na6cjMMzGK888Pu4EfeKICxTsLLP6kFKZiYchPuqEzkveI434v1tqmX1XWzWpTiZINtajmmoi6LqrposI4mHPXwE5afMddZhxGS5Kj0OOgCSz1lbwjE/iCED/n0IIzD7PgF)

Tried to get a solution which doesn't copy existing answers. I get cyclic redundancy checksum polynomial of 32-bit lengths ([crc32](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php)) for each word and then do a mod 20 and mod 11 on it to get mixed up unique values from 0 to 10 (missing 6) for each digit. Then using that unique value I find the actual digit.

```
| Word  | CRC32      | %20 | %11 | Equivalent digit |
|-------|------------|-----|-----|------------------|
| zero  | 2883514770 | 10  | 10  | 0                |
| one   | 2053932785 | 5   | 5   | 1                |
| two   | 298486374  | 14  | 3   | 2                |
| three | 1187371253 | 13  | 2   | 3                |
| four  | 2428593789 | 9   | 9   | 4                |
| five  | 1018350795 | 15  | 4   | 5                |
| six   | 1125590779 | 19  | 8   | 6                |
| seven | 2522131820 | 0   | 0   | 7                |
| eight | 1711947398 | 18  | 7   | 8                |
| nine  | 2065529981 | 1   | 1   | 9                |
```

Another 74 bytes CRC32 alternative using `%493%10`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxLC4JAFAXgvb/iIiMqPdC0h1i0609UC7GrMxD3DjPjg358pqs2HwfO4Wipp/NVzzZssKplhKN@8wujEMK1qExLcWXFEAvaXsL8dMwO@2KXpOG9NnW2i@YmyIssSJNnibXklaByWgL4D/JLryOLLhIUlxMTghsYnDSI0HBnoFE9glUjWOyRAFUrHZCahx807C3An/ngy9opJjttbj8)

Another 74 bytes CRC32 alternative using `%2326%11`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczdCoJAEAXge59ikBWVfkgtKyy66yUqQmx0F2Jm2V1/6OEzverm48A5HC31eLroyZoNlpWMcNBvfmEUQrgUpWkoLq3oY0Hr8zPJjoftLt9v0ltlqiyNpiJIszQPkuRRYCV5IagY5wD@nfzCa8miiwTFxciE4HoGJw0i1NwaqFWHYNUAFjskQNVIB6Sm4QcNezPwZzr4snaKyY6r6w8)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

```php
foreach(explode(' ',$argn)as$w)$n.=strpos(d07bfe386c,md5($w)[21]);echo+$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1LCsIwFAD3PUUogSZYxQ9VIYo7L6EuYvJqBH0vJCkVD2@MKzfDwCzGO593B1/YUwBtnICXf5AF0bCm5TrcUOrIR8lxto8peIrCzjfXHlbbtWmfthMlnpaLi1RgHE04qvwTVp@xVtWAEZLgKFUZDIGlkao3BGJ/EMKHfLoTxjw9fgE)

Another alternative with same length, takes 22nd character in the `md5` of the word (only character which gives a unique value for each word) and then uses that character to map to a digit.

Comment: This is a cool answer

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>71</s>  70 bytes

-1 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121) (use `find` in place of `index`)

```python
lambda s:int(''.join(`'rothuvsein'.find((w*3)[6])`for w in s.split()))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDgIhDAC/0hvggYMmHkx8iZrsmi1Ss7YEuqB@HvE2mcykj0bhfQ/na1/n132ZoZyI1Rrjn0JsJ5NF41YLEhsfiBdr2@7gLsebm4JkaEAMxZe0klrnXE95/BAscdr@pptAFUGbQMGKI6Y3aMyIEGTLIIyA9IgKTAO/mMX8AA)**

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>70 67 66</s>  62 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ovs*

```javascript
s=>+s.replace(/\w+ ?/g,s=>'2839016547'[parseInt(s,36)%204%13])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY29DoIwFEZ3n@IupG1A/kUd0NlnUIcGb6GGtKStYHz5inEwIS7fcHLynTsfuW2MHNxa6Rt6UXtbH0IbGxx63iBNLlMIx6SNZkzyXbFPs2pTbsl54MbiSTlqo6JiQZ6WQVZcmW@0srrHuNctFZQI/TDgJg1aIbzQaMLYauF8MPxmNv9ISs4HKNvOgcURFVj5BCFHhG@iM4jLkH8D)

Comment: `'2839016547'[parseInt(s,36)%204%13]` is [3 bytes shorter.](https://tio.run/##bY29DoJAEIR7n2IbchCR8KOoxdn7DMYEggucwdvL7YnG@O4INiTGZoov38xcy77kyirjVpouONRyYHngiE2nXAFFdCuNPxJaSpHusn2c5Jv1VpxMaRmP2vkcZnngpfHaS7JzSFKI4E1DRZqpw6ijxq99UdPdgnsQkEZ4oSURBIsfZ8Iwx2j@kab@tONaiwjf2Vr1CKyewNijBlRN60Cr@Wj4AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>107</s>, <s>91</s>, <s>77</s>, <s>90</s>, 73 bytes

-16 bytes by Sriotchilism O'Zaic

+13 bytes to remove leading zeroes

-16 bytes using `find` and a more clever indexing, but now it's basically a rip-off of the [Python 2 version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193364/)...

```python
lambda s:int(''.join(str('rothuvsein'.find((w*3)[6]))for w in s.split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY8xDoMwDEX3nsKbkwqxIHVA6kkoAxVO44o6KA7Q9vKUwNjFlp@@/7fHT/JBqtVdb@vQve59B1qzJINYPgOL0RQNxpD8NCuxYOlYemOWc2WbS2utCxEWYAEtdRw4GWvtmqFm2OCXYsACMAjllkfYyx/YlVCgC1OEtOxbwkJA/PAJlGbaUvgNjmeCQ@UjUdZmt8OgrU8wxvyBM7qd8gM)

Comment: [It's shorter if you just use the first two characters](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoQwEAS/0rckIB70JvgS8eYEB2QmxJHs@nmdPSwU9KWrytd2lfF5slY0sDjlspj6sxzsO5XKYjHcBBVYg@3Iisw4HQIxhMP/3bNs9IltmYY1dSTbHEL6xa/qrnqCcFPVFw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice one! That way, I can even drop the delimiter completely :)

Comment: With the updates to the challenge this is no longer valid since it includes leading zeros. :(

Comment: Yep, fix is expensive.

Comment: [Here is a slightly better fix](https://tio.run/##RYhBCoMwEEX3nmJ2xhbU2p3gSaSLQCfNQJkJyWisl0@zKBQ@7/F@@KgXvpdil7FxEiEDcV3Y1HR9Cm@qnu1yGy/22p4orFm9E0eJEiIxtT3xEw@T13l6dMMwNSESq7FdKSdGgT@cbBE0Cwjj76EdgalmogMS7siA9PIK6iPiFw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica Your fix is incorrect. The `lstrip` method strips every character in the string which is given as it's argument, so "eight two" becomes "ight two", as "e" gets stripped. Also, "zero zero zero" should print out "0", not give out an error.

Comment: You're both correct. lstrip does not work, I switched to a lambda instead

Comment: My version was not just to fix `lstrip` it is also 7 bytes shorter.

Comment: https://tio.run/##ZY/BDoIwDIbvPkVv2xICCd5IfBL0gKGTGuzIWhn68sjg6KVN/3z9/3b66BD4vPrLdR27173vQBpitcaUz0BsRaM1XwysSQcfPAkJIjGZkrjHxaa2qW@uqmrnQ4QExCClTCOpdc6tWZQstptLDKYAExhzyyPs5U/YSSiMD@8ImvYtJkZAegwKgjNuKbSApxnhoIaImNnsdhjcmhNMMT/jrWyn/AA

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>19</s>  17 bytes

```
Ḳµ7ị“*;nÄƲ]³Ṙ»i)Ḍ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVsApP9qZWxsef//4biywrU34buL4oCcKjtuw4TGsl3Cs@G5mMK7aSnhuIz///9maXZlIHR3byBzZXZlbiBzaXggdGhyZWUgZm91ciBvbmUgZWlnaHQgbmluZSB6ZXJv)**

Pretty much a port of my Python 2 answer.

---

Previous

```
ḲŒ¿€i@€“©¥q£½¤MÆÑ‘Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk1HJx3a/6hpTaYDkHjUMOfQykNLCw8tPrT30BLfw22HJz5qmPFwR8/////TMstSFUrK8xWKU8tS8xSKMysUSjKKUlMV0vJLixTy81IVUjPTM0oU8jKBzKrUonwA)

There is <s>quite possibly</s> a shorter way, but this is a way that first came to mind.

Comment: Removing zero from the enklact string to avoid decrementing, because not found is zero anyhow... clever!

Comment: Ah I see you did the same method, nice.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```perl6
{+uniparse 'SP'~S:g/<</,DIGIT /}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wrs0L7Mgsag4VUE9OEC9LtgqXd/GRl/HxdPdM0RBv/a/NVdxYqWCHlBxWn6RQk5mXmrx/7T80iKFkvJ8rqrUonwFMJGflwoA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                              }  # Anonymous block
                S:g/<</,DIGIT /   # Insert ",DIGIT " at
                                  # left word boundaries
           'SP'~  # Prepend 'SP' for space
  uniparse  # Parse list of Unicode names into string
 +  # Convert to integer
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#ε6è}.•ƒ/ÿßÇf•Åβ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@dxWs8MravUeNSw6Nkn/8P7D8w@3pwE5h1vPbfr/vyq1KF@hJKMoNVWhOLNCoaQ8X6E4tSw1TyE1Mz2jRCEvMy9VIR@IIUrSMsuARH5pEVgMiAE)

**Explanation:**

```python
#                 # Split the (implicit) input-string on spaces
 ε  }             # Map each string to:
  6è              #  Get the character at 0-based index 6 (with automatic wraparound)
     .•ƒ/ÿßÇf•    # Push compressed string "rothuvsein"
              Åβ  # Convert the characters from custom base-"rothuvsein" to an integer
                  # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•ƒ/ÿßÇf•` is `"rothuvsein"`.

Comment: [16 without rothuvsein](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193418/6484)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 89 bytes

```c
i,n;f(char*w){for(i=n=0;n=*w%32?n^*w:(i+=n-2)&&!printf(L"8 0  72 3  59641"+n%17),*w++;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrLCoJAFED3fsVtQJnxAT4qq2HoB/qGQGRG76JrjOZE4rdblIs2h8Ph1ElT18uCMUnD67ayoROT6SxHRSqVpELnF/mZrqE7cYwUJbkIgs3dIg2GX9gBUoAyhwJgd9xvMxaRn5UiDl0USSHn5fPBrUICLibPM5y9tO3gi470Twa3lqG1em1fmO5hweCooccn9HrUBBqbdgBC@huZkJ43L28)

Thanks to @Ceilingcat smartest tricks :

```c
- printf instead of putchar.   
- !printf instead of printf()&0. 
- And wide char !
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
•D±¾©xWÄ0•I#HèTβ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMil0MbD@07tLIi/HCLAZDrqexxeEXIuU3//1elFuUr5OelKpSU5yuUZBSlpiqk5ZcWKaRllqUqFGdWKBSnlqXmKaRmpmeUKORl5qUCAA)

Perfect tie with [the other 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/convert-a-string-of-digits-from-words-to-an-integer/193395#193395), but using a completely different approach.

```
•D±¾©xWÄ0•               # compressed integer 960027003010580400
          I#             # split the input on spaces
            H            # convert each word from hex (eg "one" => 6526)
             è           # index (with wrap-around) into the digits of the large integer
              Tβ         # convert from base 10 to integer
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
\w+
¶$&$&$&
%7=T`r\ot\huvs\ein`d`.
\D

^0+\B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP6Zcm@vQNhU1EORSNbcNSSiKyS@JySgtK45JzcxLSEnQ44px4eKKM9COceL6/z8tv7RIoaQ8n6sqtShfAUHk56Vy5WXmpSqkZqZnlCgUp5al5ikUZ1YopGWWpSpAdGUUpaaC9IIUg3UBAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\w+
¶$&$&$&
```

Put each word on its own line and triplicate it.

```
%7=T`r\ot\huvs\ein`d`.
```

Transliterate the 7th character of each line using @UnrelatedString's string.

```
\D
```

Delete all remaining non-digit characters.

```
^0+\B
```

Delete leading zeros (but leave at least one digit).

Previous 46-byte more traditional solution:

```
T`z\wuxg`E
on
1
th
3
fi
5
se
7
ni
9
\D

^0+\B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcs9CgIxFEXh/q7iNYJgo4iIrShuYMogsbiZvOYFkswPs/noaGFzqvNlVrVX22wfvnV@cdMw9/6OZDigRhwRFCcU4gxTXOBuwHO/c1e0FtKQpU4JC3OSf5LxMxuF2scqhSNNis4SdKT8VMzkatf5q94) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`z\wuxg`E
```

The words `zero`, `two`, `four`, `six` and `eight` uniquely contain the letters `zwuxg`. Transliterate those to the even digits.

```
on
1
th
3
fi
5
se
7
ni
9
```

For the odd digits, just match the first two letters of each word individually.

```
\D
```

Delete all remaining non-digit characters.

```
^0+\B
```

Delete leading zeros (but leave at least one digit).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>63 bytes</s>, <s>52 bytes</s>, 50 bytes

```
p $*.map{|d|'rothuvsein'.index (d*3)[6]}.join.to_i
```

-2 thanks to [value ink's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) tip

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! In Ruby, `$*` is an alias for `ARGV`, so feel free to use that to save extra bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## x86 machine code, 46 bytes

Hexdump:

```
57 53 33 c0 33 ff f6 01 0f 75 15 6a 0a 5b 99 f7
f3 6b ff 0a 03 fa 33 c0 38 01 75 0f 97 5b 5f c3
69 c0 26 2b aa 6e 32 01 c1 e8 02 41 eb d8
```

It's a `fastcall` function - receives a pointer to the string in `ecx`, and returns the result in `eax`.

The hashing function multiplies by a magic number `1856645926`, does a `XOR` with input byte, and shifts right by 2 bits.

Saving and restoring noclobber registers (`edi` and `ebx`) took 4 bytes, but I didn't find a more efficient way to implement this. Storing the constant 10 in `ebx` was particularly annoying!

Disassembly with corresponding code bytes:

```
57                   push        edi  ; edi = result
53                   push        ebx  ; we use ebx to store the constant 10
33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
33 FF                xor         edi,edi  
    myloop:
F6 01 0F             test        byte ptr [ecx],0Fh  ; check for end of word
75 15                jne         myhash
6A 0A                push        0Ah  
5B                   pop         ebx  
99                   cdq              ; prepare 64-bit dividend in edx:eax
F7 F3                div         eax,ebx  ; find the remainder of division by 10
6B FF 0A             imul        edi,edi,0Ah
03 FA                add         edi,edx  ; update the result
33 C0                xor         eax,eax  ; reset the hash temporary variable
38 01                cmp         byte ptr [ecx],al  ; check for end of input (here al=0)
75 0F                jne         mycontinue
97                   xchg        eax,edi  ; set the return register
5B                   pop         ebx  ; restore registers
5F                   pop         edi  ; restore registers
C3                   ret  
    myhash:
69 C0 26 2B AA 6E    imul        eax,eax,6EAA2B26h  ; hashing...
32 01                xor         al,byte ptr [ecx]  ; hashing...
C1 E8 02             shr         eax,2  ; hashing...
    mycontinue:
41                   inc         ecx  ; next input byte
EB D8                jmp         myloop
```

Equivalent C code:

```c
int doit(const char* s)
{
    int result = 0;
    unsigned temp = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int c = *s++;
        if ((c & 15) == 0)
        {
            temp %= 10;
            result = result * 10 + temp;
            temp = 0;
            if (c == 0)
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        temp *= 1856645926;
        temp ^= c;
        temp >>= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How did you find the magic numbers?

Comment: I did a search using my C code - tried all 32-bit numbers and all shifts. There are only a few possibilities - the code found only one in the range up to 2000000000.

Comment: you can use edx instead of edi (push edx before the idiv, pop eax after it, imul with ebx, add eax to edx) to save one byte.

Answer (score 3):

## ARM Thumb-2 (manual `rothuvsein`, no div, no libc) 70 bytes

Machine code:

```
b5f0 2100 2420 f000 f816 0032 18c5 3b03
bf18 f1c3 0303 5cc4 a004 f000 f80c 240a
fb01 3104 1c68 2a00 d1ec bdf0 6f72 6874
7675 6573 6e69 f07f 0300 1c5b 5cc6 b10e
42a6 d1fa 4770
```

Assembly:

```armasm
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv6t2
        .thumb
        .globl _strtoint
        .thumb_func
_strtoint:
        push    {r4-r7, lr}
        movs    r1, #0
.Lstrtoint_loop:
        movs    r4, #' '
        bl      _strfind
        movs    r2, r6
        adds    r5, r0, r3
        subs    r3, #3
        it      ne
        rsbne   r3, #3
        ldrb    r4, [r0, r3]
        adr     r0, .Lrothuvsein
        bl      _strfind
        movs    r4, #10
        mla     r1, r1, r4, r3
        adds    r0, r5, #1
        cmp     r2, #0
        bne     .Lstrtoint_loop
.Lstrtoint_loop_end:
        pop     {r4-r7, pc}

        @ naturally 4-byte aligned
        @ note: this is not null terminated - we blindly assume a match
.Lrothuvsein:
        .ascii "rothuvsein"
        @ naturally 2-byte aligned
        .thumb_func
_strfind:
        movs    r3, #-1
.Lstrfind_loop:
        adds    r3, r3, #1
        ldrb    r6, [r0, r3]
        cbz     r6, .Lstrfind_loop_end
        cmp     r6, r4
        bne     .Lstrfind_loop
.Lstrfind_loop_end:
        bx      lr
```

#### Explanation

Yet another port of the `rothuvsein` method, but this seems to be the first one in assembly. It is also done manually without the support of libc or fancy useless CISC instructions like `repne scasb`. Just plain, barebones RISC. That means that it is longer than other assembly languages.

Unlike my previous entries, I am a little more flexible with the calling convention.

While the input string (null terminated) is in `r0` just like it would be in C, the output is a 32-bit integer in `r1` instead of the traditional `r0`.

It can still be wrapped in C like so, since `r1` is still used for 64-bit integers:

```c
extern uint64_t _strtoint(const char *str);
uint32_t strtoint(const char *str)
{
    return (uint32_t)(_strtoint(str) >> 32);
}
```

Regardless of whether I care about the calling convention, I am going to have to do something with the link register so I can call my subroutine, so might as well `push` the callee-saved registers and remain mostly in line with the calling convention.

```armasm
        .globl _strtoint
        .thumb_func
_strtoint:
        push    {r4-r7, lr}
```

Initialize our accumulator/output variable to 0.

```armasm
        movs    r1, #0
```

Call our internal subroutine to find the end of the word.

`r3` will have the length of the word, and `r6` will have the last byte read. I will explain `_strfind` later.

```armasm
.Lstrtoint_loop:
        movs    r4, #' '
        bl      _strfind
```

We save a copy of the last byte read for later to tell if we reached the null terminator.

```armasm
        movs    r2, r6
```

Put the pointer to the string (advanced to the space) in `r5`.

```armasm
        adds    r5, r0, r3
```

Here is the trickiest part: **One does not simply `str+str+str` in assembly.** We need to find the index.

Specifically, if we plot it out:

```
oneoneone
      ^
fourfourfour
      ^
sevensevenseven
      ^
```

We can turn it into this:

```c
switch (strlen(str)) {
case 3: return str[0];
case 4: return str[2];
case 5: return str[1];
}
```

It can be done as `6 % strlen(str)`, but that is division. I can do better.

I could do a lookup table, but there is a better solution than that:

Remember that `r3` is essentially `strlen(str)`.

We can do this:

```armasm
        subs    r3, #3
        it      ne
        rsbne   r3, #3 @ note: rsb = Reverse SuBtract
```

The equivalent C:

```c
if ((len -= 3) != 0)
{
    len = 3 - len;
}
```

This works perfectly:

```
3 - 3       = 0
3 - (4 - 3) = 2
3 - (5 - 3) = 1
```

Now, we load the byte from the string at our offset...

```armasm
        ldrb    r4, [r0, r3]
```

...then call `_strfind` with the `rothuvsein` lookup table to find it.

```armasm
        adr     r0, .Lrothuvsein
        bl      _strfind
```

Now, we add the length to our accumulator times 10;

```armasm
        movs    r4, #10
        mla     r1, r1, r4, r3 @ r1 = r1 * 10 + len
```

Take the copy of the string we made in `r5`, advance it past the space, and put it in `r0` for the next iteration.

```armasm
        adds    r0, r5, #1
```

Then, loop if we are not at a null terminator:

```armasm
        cmp     r2, #0
        bne     .Lstrtoint_loop
```

Finally, return in `r1` by popping the link register holding the return address into the program counter (along with restoring the other registers I saved).

```armasm
.Lstrtoint_loop_end:
        pop     {r4-r7, pc}
```

_strfind subroutine

`_strfind` is the real workhorse here.

C users will find it similar to `strcspn` or `strchr`.

It is called with the null terminated string to search in `r0` and the byte to find in `r4`.

It will return the index of the match (or null terminator) in `r3` and the last byte read in `r6`.

First, initialize our counter at -1.

```armasm
_strfind:
        movs    r3, #-1
```

On each iteration, increment the counter..

```armasm
.Lstrfind_loop:
        adds    r3, r3, #1
```

Then, load `str[counter]` into `r6`

```armasm
        ldrb    r6, [r0, r3]
```

Then loop unless `r6` is `\0` or if it matches `r4`.

```armasm
        cbz     r6, .Lstrfind_loop_end
        cmp     r6, r4
        bne     .Lstrfind_loop
```

When we find it, return back to `_strtoint`.

```armasm
.Lstrfind_loop_end:
        bx      lr
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>478</s> <s>218</s> 142 bytes

-(a lot) thanks to Jo King

```cpp
int f(string s){char c[]="N02K8>IE;6";int i=0,n=0;while(s[i]){n=n*10-1;while((s[i]^s[i+1])+47!=c[++n%10]);while(s[i++]!=' '&&s[i]);}return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDBaoRADIbvPkV2S3e17sJYSlsY3VsPpdAXEBdkjBrQKDPjbqn47HYUoZeQfEl@/kT1/blSan4gVs1QIMTUGasxby/eYIgr4LxF0@cKwdhCzsQWSt@NLD0TjKrONag0S/bf4vnr/fL5IV/3cpmiRJw4EfJeU4O@SSkLRk74KRLnaIMrvboQRlkQvrztEpWGIT9GIgv@98Iw2yVHOB4Oq4icNNpBM7CcVjttTuwH3ugBbL4aYpSurNAuqa@ITysMpOew6gYLcezuWNmSIhfNsrFJC@lN8y/qDjpGsPcObK0RoewGDSXd3DPoBwzekAGpqi2wU/oD)

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU/RaoNAEHz3K5aUBq0RzqS0hdO89aEU@gMhBTlXs6B7cnempeK32zsb@rLMzO7OzqphyFqlljti1Y01QkHaOoNVf4xGS9wCVz3aoVII1tVyIXbQxH4k9GwyBU6l2HEpZKNNLO2JzjKZAuaSH3KR5TIO4qcvaX5O0sfnbPMh9u8vx7dX@bQ5pSnf58Iv/Ruk6Tk77LfbPy85G3SjYWA5r/f7ijhOoikCuAXpiFF62qILMFbEu1VMZORlpUcHReGDr1qAyHUXNm7WQkbz8oNGg2YE96XBXQwiNHo00NDVf0/fYPGKDEjtxQF7p18 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
Ḳ7ị“"c tẠ;Ḅ»iƲ€Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk3mD3d3P2qYo5SsUPJw1wLrhztaDu3OPLbpUdOahzt6/v//r1SVWpSvUFKer5CWX1qkUJxZoZCamZ5RopCXmZeqUJxalpqnkA9kpWWWpSpA1GYUpaZCSCUA)

-2 bytes from running ["rothuvsein"](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X6kqtShfIT8vVaGkPF@hJKMoNVUhLb@0SCEtsyxVoTizQqE4tSw1TyE1Mz2jRCEvE6jQkSBQeriz/VFTY1Xmo84FpzY83NX5qGvp//8A) through [user202729's string compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151721/85334).

-1 byte from stealing Jonathan Allan's zero-free enklact string, and putting it in a marginally differently structured program.

-1 byte because I actually kind of understand Jelly's dictionary-based string compression now

```
Ḳ                   Split the input on spaces,
             Ʋ€     for each word
            i       find the first 1-based index (defaulting to 0)
   “"c tẠ;Ḅ»        in "othuvseine"
 7ị                 of the element at modular index 7,
               Ḍ    and convert from decimal digits to integer.
```

I must admit, I'm disappointed I couldn't get a length reduction from `othuvseinfeld`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸mg6 ì`Î¨uv
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uG1nNiDsYM6odXagiA&input=Inplcm8gb25lIHR3byB0aHJlZSBmb3VyIGZpdmUgc2l4IHNldmVuIGVpZ2h0IG5pbmUi)

Looks like everyone else beat me to the same idea - could've saved myself the hassle of writing a script to brute force the optimal string for compression, only to find that, up to index `1,000,000` (it was early, I hadn't had my caffeine yet!), "rothuvsein" is the *only* possible string!

```
¸mg6 ì`...     :Implicit input of string
¸              :Split on spaces
 m             :Map
  g6           :  Character at index 6 (0-based, with wrapping)
     ì         :Convert from digit array in base
      `...     :  Compressed string "rothuvsein"
```

The compressed string contains the characters at codepoints `206`, `168`, `117`, `118`, `160` & `136`.

Comment: ...did you really try up to 1000000? The lcm of the lengths of the digit names is 60, so there's no point trying beyond that (60 is equivalent to 0, 61 to 1, etc).

Comment: @Grimy, it was early, I hadn't had my caffeine yet! Plugging a million into the script I wrote to generate all possibilities was as easy as any other number and saved me doing the maths on the LCM.

Answer (score 2):

## [sed -re](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 78 bytes

```
s/three/3/g;s/five/5/g;s/\w\w(\w)\w*/\1/g;s/ //g;y/eouxvgnr/12467890/;s/^0*//
```

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 110 bytes

```sql
SELECT 0+STRING_AGG(CHARINDEX(LEFT(value,2),'_ontwthfofisiseeini')/2,'')
FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT*FROM i),' ')
```

Line break is for readability only.

Input is taken via table \$i\$, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341). I could have saved 14 bytes by pre-populating a string variable, but that's only allowed if the language has no other input methods.

Explanation:

1. `STRING_SPLIT` takes the input string and separates it at the spaces
2. `CHARINDEX` takes the first 2 characters and returns the (1-based) position in the string `'_ontwthfofisiseeini'`. `'ze'` for zero is not in the string and returns 0 for "not found". The underscore ensures we only get multiples of two.
3. Divide by 2 to get the final numeral
4. `STRING_AGG` smashes the digits back together with no separator
5. `0+` forces an implicit conversion to INT and drops any leading zeros. `1*` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 83 bytes

```
fun String.d()=split(' ').fold(""){a,b->a+"rothuvsein".indexOf((b+b+b)[6])}.toInt()
```

+1 byte if you wanna support longs with `toLong()`

Same rothuvsein trick as the others, saving some precious bytes thanks to kotlin's nice `toInt()` and `fold()`. I just can't shake the feeling that some more bytes can be shaved off though...

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```scala
_.split(" ").map("rothuvsein"indexOf _.*(3)(6)).mkString.toInt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVFLS8NAEL77Kz6CYCIl1vouVPDoRQXxXLbJJF1Nd9fdSa2Kv73OJq1Q9OQlS@Z77k4oVKPWeuGsZ4T4kzfK1K2qKXc2cKVX9y7g6AjGMjy9ttpTicp6VK0pWFujGs3vA1jTvHfzUgc1a7SpoVCR4tYT3pQ3Mtmzs2cqGHftYkb@QflAHrRiMmXAjXP43AOWqoneYzyyjy6Ta9waxmQ9zYOTrDRBkuUL5dLEW563y0DaJNqUtLqvMM0P05MsPc@E8tI75GzFYA2UVEV3XSqm1HQdwjZmID2cdKNyHOOyMZ6MltSuUl9KFdzKMYnttvKsQ1WQi3C6JUx@vHrYSQA3Jg3Jwf5Gd4BaLylgf6NJC@u9SLIkSr76Z@iLJtYQ@M2C554oGeB4dJLtED7IW/yDJetqZY9SBEGvEGhJBqTrOUO2tTE5PTu/uLzatYooOj/xEtrVcLRLiBEd/vMR1mg4HP6uJMAf0x2h4F/rbw)
This is the "rothuvsein" approach in Scala. The 7th character of each (repeated) number string is extracted via `(numberString*3)(6)`. The position of this character in "rothuvsein" is then used as the correct numerical digit. The `toInt` conversion does the rest (e.g., dealing with leading zeros).

2 times 2 bytes saved thanks to @user by

1. an even more abused use of syntactic sugar :)
2. simply using `toInt` conversion rather than `BigInt` constructor

Comment: Nice answer! You can get [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##nVFLT9tAEL7zKz5ZSNhVFEKgtEQyEty4ABLijDb22NnWmd3ujkMA8dvD2E6QIjj14sd8z92JhWnMxi69C4LY/Ywbw3Vrahp7F6Wy6zsfcXwMdoJA/1obqETlAqqWC7GOTWPlZQTHzUs/L20088ZyDYOKjLSB8GwC6@TAzf9QIbhtl3MK9yZECqC1EJcRV97j7QBYmabznuFBQueSX@La1jcsyDecXw7fKSN6DUaCZGl8mgQni3YVyXJiuaT1XYWn8Y/0NEvPs2z5d/DKNkBJVRdhSyOUcl8k7rJGWsZrQSpn0JBshkfWjLzvNTQzhbT6yruKO3nWoybqaSTdEfJPrwH2GiANpzE5OtzqjlDbFUUcbjVp4UJQSZZ0kvfhLoaiiWOCPDvIIhAlI5xMT7M9wisFh/9g6c5aXaYWQbRrRFoRg2y9EOjKtiZnP89//b7Yt@pQ9H7qpbSLyXSf0EX0@OdDWdPJZPK1kgLfTPeEir9vPgA) with an underscore and more infix syntax.

Comment: Make that [62](https://tio.run/##nVFLS8NAEL77Kz6CYCIl1vouVPDoRQXxXLbJJF1Nd9fdSa2Kv73OJq1Q9OQlS@Z77k4oVKPWeuGsZ4T4kzfK1K2qKXc2cKVX9y7g6AjGMjy9ttpTicp6VK0pWFujGs3vA1jTvHfzUgc1a7SpoVCR4tYT3pQ3Mtmzs2cqGHftYkb@QflAHrRiMmXAjXP43AOWqoneYzyyjy6Ta9waxmQ9zYOTrDRBkuUL5dLEW563y0DaJNqUtLqvMM0P05MsPc@E8tI75GzFYA2UVEV3XSqm1HQdwjZmID2cdKNyHOOyMZ6MltSuUl9KFdzKMYnttvKsQ1WQi3C6JUx@vHrYSQA3Jg3Jwf5Gd4BaLylgf6NJC@u9SLIkSr76Z@iLJtYQ@M2C554oGeB4dJLtED7IW/yDJetqZY9SBEGvEGhJBqTrOUO2tTE5PTu/uLzatYooOj/xEtrVcLRLiBEd/vMR1mg4HP6uJMAf0x2h4F/rbw) if you use `toInt` instead of `BigInt`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 45 bytes

```perl6
+*.words>>.&{+(1...*.uniname.comb(.uc))}.chrs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxCoQwEAXQ3lNMJRrhwzbbLHqXbJywgsnIZIOoePYoNq97C@v8LmGj2lNfOoNVdEzDgPromhcAgxynaAPDSfg2yK5tT7ifpvKpkt0I9/SiNE@RU/GSlf6rVDur0INEvgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 88 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
$s=toInt{#i\\n<-split" "s,c<-:"rothuvsein"&i<-['0'..]|c==(n+n+n).[6]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY07C8IwFEZ3f0WI4gPb4uQgzaaD4CDo1nYIaaqB5N6S3Pr2rxsLDvLBgbOcT1ktITqsO6uZkwaicS16YgeqN3BJjvpGg1EQhFug59CUJeRpaK0hznhIVJ6uuEc6d5egDfCxydNisphkWfVSQkxh3m@WFcvqHQ8k@67oX1o2YgVvsPOMrsgTxh/aI/sDQfMqflRj5SnEdLuL6ztIZ9RP9lZSg959AQ)

Heavily based on [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193364/58563).
Uses a comprehension for indexing instead of `indexOf` / `elemIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 38 bytes

```
('b\e~mjPxw['i.[:u:70+1#.15|3&u:)&>@;:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcu9CsIwFIbhvVfxodBjUUOLFCGiCIKTg7jWSTkxKZhA@ouItx5tB4d3eeEpw0SQwlaCsEAK@WspcLicjmFGtyt/nuW57woyopCNXKfzbCqy/L2KG5nEu/1GhiSK@K4dFOjF3sFZRt051NozQ7nGQ5mWUZkeFbdsweaha1hjmf50ECMf9ggofAE)

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 160 bytes

```
Function e(s)
s = Split(s, " ")
For i = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
s(i) = Int((InStr("ontwthfofisiseeini", Left(s(i), 2)) + 1) / 2)
Next
e = Val(Join(s, ""))
End Function
```

Matches the first two characters in a string, zero excluded.

Comment: (1/3) Great approach here, but it looks like you failed to count the newlines as bytes, and that you can get the bytecount way down if you use some tricks. Namely, there is no need to decaler the `" "` in the `Split` as that is the default value, `Lbound(s)` will always be zero and you can drop `(...)+1` if you add a space to the beginning of the `InStr` data. Asside from that, you are better off using either a string or variant to handle holding the data coming out of the `InStr` statement as you dont need to use `(i)` or `Join(s,"")`. Oh and `Int(a/b)` is the same as `a\b`.

Comment: (2/3) Using these, and a `for each` loop you can get your function down to 101 bytes as `Function G(x):For Each c In Split(x):G=10*G+InStr(" ontwthfofisiseeini",Left(c,2))\2:Next:End Function` or 101 bytes as a sub thet implicitly prints the output to the debug window as `Sub F(x):For Each c In Split(x):v=10*v+InStr(" ontwthfofisiseeini",Left(c,2))\2:Next:Debug.?v:End Sub`. If you restrict your answer you can even get it to 81 bytes as a Excel VBA immediate window function as `For Each c In Split([A1]):v=10*v+InStr(" ontwthfofisiseeini",Left(c,2))\2:Next:?v`.

Comment: (3/3) I highly recommend that you go take a look at our [Tips for golfing in VBA Page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5175/61846) for more info on these approaches. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｉ⍘⭆⪪Ｓ §ι⁶rothuvsein
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwymxODW4BMhP14BQvokFGsEFOZklGp55BaUlUDlNHQUlBSUg6VjimZeSWqGRqaNgpgkSLcovySgtK07NzFPS1NS0/v8/Lb@0SKGkPJ/rv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Port of @KevinCruijssen's 05AB1E answer. Explanation:

```
    Ｓ               Input string
   ⪪                Split on spaces
  ⭆                 Map over words and join
       ι            Current word
      §             Cyclically indexed
        ⁶           Literal `6`
 ⍘       rothuvsein Custom base conversion
Ｉ                   Cast to string for implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 48 bytes

```powershell
+-join($args|%{'rothuvsein'.indexof(($_*3)[6])})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADAyxhqUT9Bl4mIoDUNcWPVjB5n32YOLEDRgvfMTbujC0ostMW3eiRhsvmM4ILsXFjhQqOUmOtej8OkP83MNxByKsgGM/0)

Uses the same `rothuvsein` trick as others, thanks to Jonathan Allan. Expects input arguments via splatting, which on TIO manifests as separate command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Batch, 169 bytes

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@set z=zeontwthfofisiseeini
:a
@set b=%1
@for /l %%c in (0,2,18)do @if "!b:~0,2!"=="!z:~%%c,2!" set/aa=a*10+%%c/2&shift&goto a
@echo %a%
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 26 bytes

```apl
10⊥'rothuvsein'⍳7⊢/⍤⍴¨≠⍛⊆⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0NHnUtVS/KL8koLStOzcxTf9S72fxR1yL9R71LHvVuObTiUeeCR72zH3W1Pepd8T8NqOdRb9@jruZHvWtA0uuNH7VNBJoWHOQMJEM8PIP/pymo5@elKpSU5yuUZBSlpkJIdS6geFVqUb4CmICqUAcA)

A simple function which checks the first two letters of each word.

-30 bytes from Adám using Kevin Cruijssen's idea.

### Explanation(old)

```apl
     {⍕2÷⍨1-⍨(2↑⍵)(⍸⍷)'zeontwthfofisiseeinite'} inner fn: 
             (2↑⍵)                              take first two letters
                  (⍸⍷)'zeontwthfofisiseeinite'} find index of the letters in hardcoded string
       2÷⍨1-⍨                                   subtract 1, divide by 2
      ⍕                                         stringify
{⍎⊃,/{⍕2÷⍨1-⍨(2↑⍵)(⍸⍷)'zeontwthfofisiseeinite'}¨' '(≠⊆⊢)⍵} ⍵ → input
                                                ' '(≠⊆⊢)⍵  split input on spaces
   ,/                                                      join output of inner fn
 ⍎⊃                                                        execute it
```

Comment: [42](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0NHnUtNTq8/VHvCiONR13Nj3qXPOrd8aht4qPe7epVqfl5JeUlGWn5aZnFmcWpqZl5mepAlZqHVjzqXPCod/ajrjYg938a0KhHvX1g7Wse9W45tN4YZELf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NQT0/L1WhpDxfoSSjKDUVQqpzAcWrUovyFcAEVIU6AA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Comment: [26](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/w0NHnUtVS/KL8koLStOzcxTf9S72fxR1yL9R71LHvVuObTiUeeCR72zH3W1Pepd8T8NqOdRb9@jruZHvWtA0uuNH7VNBJoWHOQMJEM8PIP/pymo5@elKpSU5yuUZBSlpkJIdS6geFVqUb4CmICqUAcA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online") using [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216977/43319) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 27 bytes

```
10/"rothuvsein"?(*|7#)'" "\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEWvMoyLtoJUV4IuvIjbn2YQZiBJo4h3j6ahFNwMw@e99zjopKW4y@k4crDk5xwhyrd@/znvho6J78V1PTubA6Wn8ZXfCEbbMcU6/t7KUPIBoEVxkkFRXhSRoQSZfCKVzWlsJar5T7Vky9XS0rS281C@)

Another port of [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193395/98547).

- `" "\` split input on spaces
- `(*|7#)'` take the last character of each word (repeated to be of length seven)
- `"rothuvsein"?` find index of character in "rothuvsein" (i.e. the seventh character of "zero" repeated is "r", which is at index 0)
- `10/` convert from a list of digits to a decimal number

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

I put two versions of my explanation just for fun :)

Split the input **`i`** into words and loop over it using list comprehension.
For all the words find the location of the first 2 letters in a lookup table (*"zeontwthfofisiseeini"*), making sure to divide by two - with **`//`** for floor division, finally use **`"".join(`** to combine into a string and **`int(`** to convert to integer and remove leading zero(s).

```python
lambda i:int("".join([str("zeontwthfofisiseeini".find(x[:2])//2)for x in i.split()]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBDoIwEIThV9n01F4g0RuJT4IcELYyBndJuwL68gh6meRPJt/0tkHlvHWX6za2z1vfEiqIeeeKh0J8nS1592EVW2yIGpGRmSFwRYT0fq2rUxPK8hSiJloJQijyNMJ8aELYpnRw3WEkpd9EzEyM@2AkECZblDLPLKR7ZawU9ZX@XxsSs9udLw)

- `lambda i:` lambda function instead of using a `def` function
- `[for x in]` use list comprehension to check through the input
- `i.split` split the input at spaces (default delimiter)
- `"zeontwthfofisiseeini".find(x[:2])` find the location of the first two characters of **x** in a lookup list
- `//2` floor divide output of `.find` because it's checking the first 2 chars
- `str()` convert position to string
- `"".join()` combine output of list comprehension to a string
- `int()` convert string to int and remove leading zero(s)

Also, this is accidentally similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193359/100140) answer but I made mine before looking at the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 63 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.875 bytes

```
⌈ƛ₀ʁ∆ċḟ;ṅ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIuKMiMab4oKAyoHiiIbEi+G4nzvhuYXijIoiLCIiLCJcInplcm8gemVybyB6ZXJvIG9uZVwiXG5cImZvdXIgc2l4IGZpdmUgb25lXCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
110010010001010010110111001001001001010010011010110111110111010
```

```
⌈ƛ₀ʁ∆ċḟ;ṅ⌊­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
⌈           # ‎⁡split on spaces
 ƛ     ;    # ‎⁢map over each 
      ḟ     # ‎⁣their index in the list
  ₀ʁ∆ċ      # ‎⁤0-9 as words
        ṅ⌊  # ‎⁢⁡convert back to number
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## **[BaCon](http://www.basic-converter.org), <s>83</s> 72 bytes**

Assuming the string is provided in w$, this code looks up the index in "zeontwthfofisiseeini" using a regular expression based on the unique first 2 characters of each word. The index is then divided by 2 providing the correct result.

```
FOR x$ IN w$:r=r*10+REGEX("zeontwthfofisiseeini",LEFT$(x$,2))/2:NEXT:?r
```

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, <s>76</s> 64 bytes

More of the same, but with a pinch of AWK sparkling magic.

Edit: at first, I didn't looked for the answers, and my result was actually similar to some of them. I'm mesmerized by all these ingenious solutions.

```
{i=OFS=e;for(;NF>i++;)$i=index("othuvsein",substr($i$i$i,7,1))}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OtPW3y3YNtU6Lb9Iw9rPzS5TW9taUyXTNjMvJbVCQym/JKO0rDg1M09Jp7g0qbikSEMlEwR1zHUMNTVrDf//T8svLVIoKc/nqkotyldAEPl5qVwA)

````
{
i=OFS=e;     # We start setting the _i_ variable and the
             # Output Field Separator as the _e_ variable, which is
             # just empty, for never being assigned anything,
             # so _e_ is both evaluated as zero for _i_ and null for _OFS_
             # (thanks Brian Kernighan for that!)
for(;
    NF>i++;  # the looping goes on until _i_ reaches the Number of Fields (NF).
   )         # also, _i_ is incremented by 1 each turn.

     $i=                          # $i is each field text
        index("othuvsein",        # we get this magic Klingon and locate the
              substr($i$i$i,7,1)  # 7th letter of the input concatenated 3 times
             )                    # this has the same effect as looking
                                  # for the second to last letter on the word.
        
}
1            # finally, we print all the $i together
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 55 bytes

```perl
for$b(z,on,w,th,u,iv,x,v,g,ni){s/$b/@a/eg;$#a++}s/\D//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcSxCoMwEADQ/b5CqIPi2djBSQoOXfsHXRTOeCB3ksQolv56U@gb3kpuaVOa1OVjcaIK7hhm3JAjHhjRonD59iYfTT8Ysl1@Garq483rYYxNXT/ci7JLJznN/qkQhF2zMDsimHRzMHEk8HyAp0gCxHYOICz01TWwik/1s702tybV6/ID)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (pure), <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```bash
r=rothuvsein
for j in $@
do
s=$j$j$j
t=${r%${s:6:1}*}
((i=i*10+${#t}))
done
echo $i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs7CsMwEAV7neJBFLCdJm5SGAS5Sj6raF1oYSXbIUZnV2SmG2aejxRqVaeSw7Im4mi8KGZwhL2bt5jk7HxgsrO7nu2epts0lqGYrmPHw3i92P2US9@3OpKhVxBYrrX@SAVNIW@CHJQIXhaF55WQ@ItEK0UQf0JG5BYexx8)

Literally just the same as every other `rothuvsein` entry. Concatenates three times and gets it at index 6.

First version which uses no string concatenation: (85 bytes)

```bash
r=rothuvsein
for j in $@
do
t=${r%${j:$((6%${#j})):1}*}
((i=i*10+${#t}))
done
echo $i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvLCsIwEIXhfZ7igBHSurEbF4WCr@JlYqaLDEzSKJY8e4y7w8d/7rcUWtNFJYetJOJovChWcIS9mqeYvNhdj3ZfZ@vcpY/DWodhnupYjXO88DidT11z195HMvQIAsuttS@poBPyW5CDEsHLpvBcCIk/SFQogvgVMiL38P/4AQ)

Pass the string as command line arguments. Expects `$i` to be unset.

Ungolfed version:

```bash
# Default value is zero
val=0
# declare our lookup table
lut=rothuvsein
# loop through command line arguments
for word in $@
do
    # The index is at 6 % len(word) (see my Thumb submission)
    idx=$(( 6 % ${#word} ))
    # chr = word[6 % len(word)]
    chr=${word:$idx:1}
    # Find a substring using a modified technique from the linked SO post
    substr=${lut%$chr*}
    # Add the length to val * 10
    (( val = val * 10 + ${#substr} ))
done
# Echo the result
echo $val
```

[How to check if a string contains a substring in Bash - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5032641/4014461)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
ssm`x."evt8†À‘"@d6c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7g4N6FCTym1jKnE4lDb4YZDE5UcUsyS//9XqkotyldIyy8tUigpz1cCAA)

Translates literally to `print(int("".join(map(lambda d: str("rothuvsein".index(d[6%len(d)])), eval(input()).split()))))` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

### Lua (110 bytes)

---

A translation to Lua of the `rothuvsein` trick, sorry. Note that we use 7 instead of 6 because Lua counts from 1, as sane humans do.

```lua
function x(s)z=""for w in s:gmatch("%a+")do z=z..(("rothuvsein"):find(w:rep(3):sub(7,7))-1) end return z+0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, <s>135</s> <s>128</s> 91 bytes

```swift
let f={Int(.init(($0+"").split{$0<"0"}.map{[_]("2839016547")[Int($0,radix:36)!%204%13]}))!}
```

This is pretty much a port of [@Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193363/118665).

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 64 bytes

```
{split(" ").fold(0){a,b->10*a+"rothuvsein".indexOf((b+b+b)[6])}}
```

Improving upon [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193488).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY65DsIwEET7fMXKlU0OhYYCiXQUVBSUiMK5iIVZR84mHJG/PTgRiFlpi3nFvJshrXCqe4S7VMgFjAH4DFKDLwtSBrdwIqvwmngaZ3BAgh1MY9dqRZwBE0ltdMlTMcooj7N1upIhs4aafugqhSxRWFbPY815HvoT581FODfNM9Ja@fKE1aa3QA/DImDvyhr4P4PVMmH3smi@enNa70Qa@U@TKxJioS5w0wc)