# Twist on words to numbers

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, conversion

### The Goal

The goal of this question is to put a twist on **[this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/convert-a-string-of-digits-from-words-to-an-integer)**. Your answer should be able to convert an array of words associated with integers into those integers. As an extra challenge, allow support for  , `+`, `-`, and `_` in between numbers such as `sixty seven`, `sixty+seven`, `sixty-seven`, or `sixty_seven`.

### Examples

General Example: `one, twenty-two, eleven, thirty+five, forty eight` => `1, 22, 11, 35, 48`.
General Example: `ninety_two, eighty one, zero, seventy+seven, nine` => `92, 81, 0, 77, 9`.
Javascript/Node.JS Example: `['five', 'twenty+eight', 'fifty_two', 'thirty', 'zero']` => `[5, 28, 52, 30, 0]`

### Assumptions

- There are no negative numbers
- The applicable numbers only need to be `0-99`
- The array will not be empty

### Scoring

As this is code-golf, let the answer with the fewest amount of bytes win. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, but... If `twenty+two` is 22, why `twenty-two` isn't 18?

Comment: @tsh what do you mean?

Comment: Welcome to CG&CC! I VTCed as "needs details or clarity" because there's no actual, self-contained specification of what words the input could consist of or how to handle them. I also don't feel like the challenge gains anything from the array I/O, as opposed to converting a single number, but that's more subjective. This could benefit from some Sandbox time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 127 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(s=>s.replace(/[a-z]+/g,s=>t+=Buffer(`3!S~0?.']5~g)~~~#I*~{2"&+,/-~4~$%q~(1`)[parseInt(s,36)%620%546%115%37]-33,t=0)|t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5LT4QwFIX3/gp8IK28hmHAFWPibtYuCZlp8JapwRbbyoTR9K8jD9HEuDwn937feSEtUaVkjfa5eIaeZj3JtiR4JQ1S2VYFEpqalIDCnPjnwg0rb6i1mz2@UwoSHeLLJ7N6CJwiMRU2xlzv7szH@urW9ULfbMyN/WZQdMB5Q6SCHddIeXGK7XS9spNNakdRYsf3hR/Hns5W@FPjvhRciRqCWlSIotwRHBzPcvQJuO58fRJjghpa4FN/ZFJ3LmXtdEbFkCxg1VE7BcYXf2mccdDdfsGMd531rTiDnFo1sgemWhzj07@0xTqPc2ftuILRX8m88EcwcPov)

Below is a summary of the hash function, which gives a result in \$[0..36]\$ with a few unused slots.

```
 string      | base 36 -> dec. | mod 620 | mod 546 | mod 115 | mod 37
-------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+--------
 'zero'      |  1652100        |   420   |   420   |   75    |  1
 'one'       |  31946          |   326   |   326   |   96    |  22
 'two'       |  38760          |   320   |   320   |   90    |  16
 'three'     |  49537526       |   146   |   146   |   31    |  31
 'four'      |  732051         |   451   |   451   |   106   |  32
 'five'      |  724298         |   138   |   138   |   23    |  23
 'six'       |  36969          |   389   |   389   |   44    |  7
 'seven'     |  47723135       |   495   |   495   |   35    |  35
 'eight'     |  24375809       |   509   |   509   |   49    |  12
 'nine'      |  1097258        |   478   |   478   |   18    |  18
 'ten'       |  38111          |   291   |   291   |   61    |  24
 'eleven'    |  882492287      |   407   |   407   |   62    |  25
 'twelve'    |  1807948346     |   446   |   446   |   101   |  27
 'thirteen'  |  2310701170991  |   351   |   351   |   6     |  6
 'fourteen'  |  1229565944111  |   371   |   371   |   26    |  26
 'fifteen'   |  33766692143    |   423   |   423   |   78    |  4
 'sixteen'   |  62095095599    |   619   |   73    |   73    |  36
 'seventeen' |  80156542487855 |   95    |   95    |   95    |  21
 'eighteen'  |  1137277763375  |   115   |   115   |   0     |  0
 'nineteen'  |  1842973464623  |   103   |   103   |   103   |  29
 'twenty'    |  1807950886     |   506   |   506   |   46    |  9
 'thirty'    |  1782948454     |   194   |   194   |   79    |  5
 'forty'     |  26350054       |   54    |   54    |   54    |  17
 'fifty'     |  26054566       |   306   |   306   |   76    |  2
 'sixty'     |  47912902       |   542   |   542   |   82    |  8
 'seventy'   |  61849184038    |   278   |   278   |   48    |  11
 'eighty'    |  877529158      |   378   |   378   |   33    |  33
 'ninety'    |  1422047446     |   566   |   20    |   20    |  20
```