# Worded Calculator

Tags: code-golf

A simplistic version of [English numeral calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12757/english-numeral-calculator)

#### Task

Write a program that takes a string as input and outputs the result of the expression.

#### Rules

The input string will be worded and not numeral.

There will be no parentheses.

Order of calculation will be divide,multiply,subtract then add.

For same operations, the calculations must be done from left to right.

All input numbers will be integers from -999 to 999 (both inclusive)

Output will be an integer of any range.

Division will always be perfectly divisible and zero will never be a denominator.

Restriction of case for input is optional. You don't have to check for the validity of the input.

#### Number Format

```
0 to 20 -> zero,one,two...nineteen,twenty
21 to 99 -> twenty one,twenty two.....ninety eight,ninety nine
100 to 999 -> one hundred, one hundred one, one hundred two...one hundred ten....two hundred fifty....nine hundred ninety eight,nine hundred ninety nine
```

For negative numbers: Add `minus` to its positive equivalent

#### Operation Format

```
Addition: one plus two
Subtraction: one minus two
Multiplication: one time two #Note that for one on the left of multiplication, it is one time and not times.
                two times one hundred
Division: forty divided by two
```

#### Examples:

```
o/p <- input

20     four times five
35     twenty plus fifteen
70     fifty plus five times four
-90    minus one time ninety
25     twenty one minus minus four
45     ninety divided by two
700    one time seven hundred 
555    one hundred eleven times two plus three hundred thirty three
99     one hundred plus minus one
45     forty five plus two hundred times zero
 4     four
-3     three minus three minus three
```

**This is code-golf so shortest code wins**

Comment: Ignore my now deleted comment.. The expression is the input, and the number is the output.. I had it the other way around because usually left is input and right is output.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12757/english-numeral-calculator) - I think that's close enough to be considered as such.

Comment: It's very close indeed. But I think this one is better specified and has more reasonable limitations.

Comment: @Arnauld I will keep this open then but if others think differently, just mark it as duplicate.

Comment: I say `one times two`. Is using `time` normal?

Comment: I could see it being parsed as "one time, two" but I still would think that "one times two" is perfectly acceptable from a mathematical standpoint

Comment: You mention that (in my words) answers are free to require whatever casing they want, but is the input guaranteed to only contain letters and spaces?

Comment: I think you meant 'one time**s** seven hundred'?

Comment: @ouflak No, this user seems to think that 1 times X is always written 1 time X...

Comment: There's a related discussion on another stack [about this _times_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133093/the-word-times-instead-of-multiplied-by).

Comment: So, one time two is creating a lot of confusion, should I remove it and just do one times two? I meant to say that one time and times both are valid for one so you have to consider for both. I will edit the question then.

Answer (score 18):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>257</s> <s>252</s> <s>249</s> 235 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
s=>eval(s.split` `.map(w=>(i='zeonwohrr44fx3n5t54nn3leel8tou7fn7n98etetwthfofisiseeinihuplmitidiby'.match(/../g).findIndex(x=>~(w+w.length+w).search(x)))>28?n+' '+'+-*/ '[n='',i-29]:(n=+n+(i<28?i<20?i:i*10-180:n*99),''),n='').join``+n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBbuIwEIbv@xRWL7YJGNpSFVBDz/sMq5VIyZhMZcaR7STQw74668S7VNoN6mVkeb75/5n/vWgLv3dYhxnZEi46v/h8C21hhFe@Nhh2bKeORS26fCsw5x9gqbOVc8ulPj3SU3haEj0aALMKtnnW9EzrFQQIXai01ejRAyBh1dTmiAFLfDvzKBj2lZgrNT9IpZHK71TCSZzy7S/RZZ0yQIdQZZ1UHgoX0ZOUcvuweqWMM57xbDaZM/6Dcs6nOHtY/9wIyjPKBL5EKJbFK25wcr@Y3a8WG5qs13LKuZz2A1K9W6TdLiN52Vvy1oAy9iC0uNO2cSzgETzT2MKdlN/@IUIHFM6sNk2P6ABAI1TfuUIt/JWM6iPwESlylhLGCAnC@bZ1D6aRVG@oJhlWYosllOztzEJnR7irr4cWiFUNlQ7KG@CfLgMzwOmsqJtODZWDTyZU6OICw@cXcsP0NYaxPG0vNUSZnKLl1WdY4gOcHR0cDSdtmhz/e0f@8hs)

### How?

Once the input string has been split into words, each word \$W\$ of length \$L\$ is converted to an index \$i\$ by looking for the first 2-character key substring that can be found in \$W+L+W\$.

#### Numbers

```
 index | word              | word + length + word         | key substring
-------+-------------------+------------------------------+---------------
    0  | "zero"            | "zero4zero"                  | "ze"
    1  | "one"             | "one3one"                    | "on"
    2  | "two"             | "two3two"                    | "wo"
    3  | "three"           | "three5three"                | "hr"
    4  | "four"            | "four4four"                  | "r4"
    5  | "five"            | "five4five"                  | "4f"
    6  | "six"             | "six3six"                    | "x3"
    7  | "seven"           | "seven5seven"                | "n5"
    8  | "eight"           | "eight5eight"                | "t5"
    9  | "nine"            | "nine4nine"                  | "4n"
   10  | "ten"             | "ten3ten"                    | "n3"
   11  | "eleven"          | "eleven6eleven"              | "le"
   12  | "twelve"          | "twelve6twelve"              | "el"
   13  | "thirteen"        | "thirteen8thirteen"          | "8t"
   14  | "fourteen"        | "fourteen8fourteen"          | "ou"
   15  | "fifteen"         | "fifteen7fifteen"            | "7f"
   16  | "sixteen"         | "sixteen7sixteen"            | "n7"
   17  | "seventeen"       | "seventeen9seventeen"        | "n9"
   18  | "eighteen"        | "eighteen8eighteen"          | "8e"
   19  | "nineteen"        | "nineteen8nineteen"          | "te"
   20  | "twenty"          | "twenty6twenty"              | "tw"
   21  | "thirty"          | "thirty6thirty"              | "th"
   22  | "forty"           | "forty5forty"                | "fo"
   23  | "fifty"           | "fifty5fifty"                | "fi"
   24  | "sixty"           | "sixty5sixty"                | "si"
   25  | "seventy"         | "seventy7seventy"            | "se"
   26  | "eighty"          | "eighty6eighty"              | "ei"
   27  | "ninety"          | "ninety6ninety"              | "ni"
   28  | "hundred"         | "hundred7hundred"            | "hu"
```

#### Operators

```
 index | word              | word + length + word         | key substring
-------+-------------------+------------------------------+---------------
   29  | "plus"            | "plus4plus"                  | "pl"
   30  | "minus"           | "minus5minus"                | "mi"
   31  | "times" or "time" | "times5times" or "time4time" | "ti"
   32  | "divided"         | "divided7divided"            | "di"
   33  | "by"              | "by2by"                      | "by"
```

#### Interpretation

The current number is stored in \$n\$, which is initialized to an empty string. Given the index \$i\$ of the next word, the following logic applies:

```javascript
i > 28 ?                  // if the word is an operator:
  n +                     //   append n (which is either an empty string or a number)
  ' ' +                   //   append a space
  '+-*/ '[n = '', i - 29] //   reset n to an empty string and append the operator
                          //   the useless keyword 'by' is translated into a harmless space
: (                       // else:
    n =                   //   update n:
      +n + (              //     force the coercion of the current value of n to a number
        i < 28 ?          //     if the word is not 'hundred':
          i < 20 ?        //       if the value of the word is less than 'twenty':
            i             //         add i
          :               //       else:
            i * 10 - 180  //         add i * 10 - 180 (e.g. 'fifty' -> 23 * 10 - 180 = 50)
        :                 //     else:
          n * 99          //       multiply n by 100 by adding 99 * n to itself
      ),                  //
    ''                    //   remove this word from the original string
  )                       //
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>170 139 129 128 124</s> 122 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to nwellnhof!*

```perl6
{S:g/(<:N>+)+%\s/({'+'X$0})/.EVAL}o{S:g/" ҈"/00/}o{TR"⁢ŉ؊⟠"*/൰ "}o*.words>>.&{chr first *.uniname.comb(.uc),1..*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHNTtwwED7jpxhFFJIsOGFh2y6UlXroreIAFUIqHJbNhFhK7JXtLNqucuit7UuA@gS98Ah9gZ56RLzIMrG7QdAcLHu@n/lmMkVdvl5Wc9jI4RCWi5P9qyR8t3806kW9V@cmCRebvc2z9bSJEv7h9P3HRjlKAH@@BUmaJvT@dBw8fP35@/vfHw83t0Gc3N/9gqBRMb9WOjOjEd9YTAoNudDGQsxrKeS4Qj5R1WXI60m0tcN53CwPWK40hKWQaCJYsDUKtT6mUNxMS2HD5NxAHEOfyEl0wNbMuMU/71zA4Qjy0F2jLQigvaYXUcAatuyn0H65qjVYUaGhGDNkuwNXttco7RymZd3Wc4so2Zt/Cnp2yAxXYvJh20NHqYQkUEmPAU2Fds76z5xb1PP86fR7nuIFkImZyDCDyzmJFLV35p2twRlKKGqZaSKxwWCwglc1LB3FByQLH9oWGp84thCaerkiGw7hpYeTdAOtEtL/IJEb33uSeefo2n1BrdgedDtm27t@fNfdG/53Z/23joTiqmhX/mxDFuUj)

`unival` to the rescue again! This is (currently) even beating golfing languages like [`05AB1E`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175377/76162)!

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*.words     # Split by word boundaries (in this case spaces)
       >>.{                            }  # Map each word to
           chr first             ,1..*    # The first character where:
                     *.uniname      # The unicode name of that character
                                    # e.g. DIGIT FIVE
                      .comb(.uc)    # Contains the uppercase of the word
{             }o  # Pass this list to another function
                  # That converts the list to a string
 TR"⁢ŉ؊⟠"*/൰ "    #"# And parse out the garbage characters that were wrong
                  # INVISIBLE TIMES => "*"
                  # LOZENGE DIVIDED BY HORIZONTAL RULE => "/"
                  # ARABIC-INDIC PER TEN THOUSAND SIGN => "൰" (value ten)
                  # LATIN SMALL LETTER N PRECEDED BY APOSTROPHE => " "
{S:g/" ҈"/00/}o   # Replace the character for "hundred" with 00

{                                }o   # And finally combine with
 S:g/(<:N>+)+%\s/   # Substitute each number-like character separated by spaces
                /({'+'X$0})/   # With the numbers prefixed by '+'s, in brackets
               # This works because Perl 6 supports numeric unicode literals, like
               # ፳ => 20, ፴ => 30, ፺ => 90, etc.
                            .EVAL   # And finally evaluate the whole expression
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>333</s> <s>...</s> <s>284</s> <s>277</s> 275 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval(''.join((list('+-/*')+[`N(w,0)*100+N(w,2)`])['pmdt'.find(w)]for w in re.split(' *(?:(p|m)|(t|d)i|by).*? ',s)if w))
N=lambda x,y:sum(10*(w[-3:]in'lveen')+'zeontwthfofisiseeiniteel'.find(w[:2])/2*10**('y'in w)for w in x.rpartition('hundred')[y].split())
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTRjtowEHznK1bqg@0QOA6KKpBO9wf8AEW60DjNVokdJQshJ/6dem3io6Iv7MYez4zHK5qBSmuWt@Lt563K6mOeQbfV56ySQsz/WDRSVtiRFNPZSyLUdP@xk326UMnrYjHldqk@DmovmjonMS/Q5LJXh8K20AMaaPW8ayp05yGR71vZXGt1lXTNFV6Pg5on7yDSTmEBvVKT3dvdwiUdtt2plq@LRPb72Wp7QCOqs9bGWRCf2hrqqSxsgR12WqNB0roa9ffb5UG9LJ3FJJFiEM5Hr6Kly7xtspaQ0BopypPJW50LtR8Od6vOCNaNbcm5vzUtGoJCisKeWiCsdQcFnrVQKSwXk7hNvTY0QFOdeL8gbzWF1foLwssRcdYjmeNl5I8HshqNA1kTMGDQaBoYNNs8SzIsHAi/I@HyQTowQI5nzHUOxwGotwz6/gCKep0@awMxGfa2gG87S26/zBzWRclga9y3hkoXBLaA@lQRugR/ZRxtCkiAD7fITA7GUrj2v6p3KdCVVw7BOIchLCpb/YWhElt3Fb/I3tbr9f/J/NmYJEM3m4fHsMzi3yGIOLUo4fU/dfsUUbASSJ96/0CrSUBPJpySOdU8clJ4shTYIBdOn4s/5hr/Zlx5slzt8OILx8GNxt8lccMP6ReqcctNQRUO@WR0WGXC2N/HMfDGlgnGD89/7/2s3HuKGm7SosYQFMaGx3okH76oh0g8RFo3xNsJhDh30qXj/j7SENjtLw)

Answer (score 5):

## Wolfram Language <s>95 94</s> 82 bytes

```
Interpreter["SemanticExpression"][#~StringReplace~{"me "->"mes ","plus m"->"m"}]&
```

`#` represents the input for the pure function.

If necessary,`StringReplace` replaces "time " with times ", "plus minus" with "minus" (through `"me "->"mes "`,`"plus m"->"m`", respectively). The shortened replacement forms, suggested by `lirtosiast`, saved 12 bytes.

`Interpreter["SemanticExpression"]` does all the rest.

Comment: Can you change `"time "->"times "` to `"me"->"mes"` and `"plus minus"->"minus"` to `"plus m"->"m"`?

Comment: Yes.  Excellent suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>166</s> <s>147</s> <s>141</s> <s>139</s> 135 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„byK“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š—¿áÓÁÏ“#vyN:}'tK'…§¦'+T«:'°¡„ *т«©:.•1×j›o!ĆÖ•3ôŽ9oS:'y®¨:©“‰´Øè„Æ€ººß“'tK#UX¡εð¡õK2ôJ.EO}®áX"+-**/"S:Sðì.ιJ.E
```

Way too long.. Will try to golf it down from here.

-4 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.
-2 bytes thanks to *@JoKing*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PY7PSwJREMf/lZceFpQ2qlN775JQBwu8JvvMF7kb7lPZg/DyIN2CioyIcoNM0dSDC7UQwkx7CoT@hfePbCNCl4Hvj/nMuN5xUfAk0eqp6Oe0eoQAO7o1glCrB61eyMd3rbo4@mnjZXwdBziBefwBE3iNu1rdwhwDvMELvKLldN3ft5qGzBla9eANekb2EIaWAVMIiMQyvy0YwsAyibyJnVOtInftu413pLdxFn/tuHnL8GEMfQsGBNRqCjO8x/7yj/byrwgifKaEjqSPChAsQiQ4hrktnO2ZuwdNGGNQSGXXM5mNVN7K4xRH5uKToiSRDZeVa45d5TaTDe5Iny0tW9SFTVZxJaWocI9VhFPzWEmUqOTxOnfY@RkZslzl/B/CxUlZcspW7dWU3PkD) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bVFNSxtRFN3Pr3iNi4FEI21XzkJXbhpoF7HgtmFezJM4I5OXkRGFp4vQXaEtVaRUR/CLRM0iAQ0U4d7OqiD0L7w/kr6PGBnazZv3zj3n3HPvhK0PNUbHO3GyVCBzi6SwlIyl@FFLKlJ8hxQP5H4PhlIcSXGqcLyW4gR7vzv4MfucpXgLD9kd3MJZdiLFV3jAFL/gHn5S4pk4eevturziSnEOF3Dullag67nQh1Q5keKffejClVdWzi/xYF2KUfjiVwe/qfdrHGQ/F8Kq5yZwA5ceXClDKfowwEO81Dk6OtcIRnisKqrJzPtVSB@HqMxxWHmFgzfl5Xe7cIPpaqE0VyzOF6peFfvYKz/eq9J4dlwP2xHhbIO2SJ3F1OFbNOAJ2Wy2NVDnlAaO/k6hmD7RldLZYIFCw8CCJGAB5cmTiYYtwZ5GYSnEZzHzqU9qCeFboTN1aNGYBqTRDvyI@gae3AltmpJtrjQ2EG9E9JnDGyxS5gbMiQ13Gtaph5pmhrEuym7qYRps0yh0TGDbwWr/uTs5pR1bQ/nxJp6TLZht2jn/MwJlaw299dzmuPoL9pbbggmpj78).

**Explanation:**

```python
„byK                 # Remove "by" from the (implicit) input-string
“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š—¿áÓÁÏ“
                     # Push string "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve"
 #                   # Split by spaces
  v   }              # Loop over each of these items:
   yN:               #  Replace the item with its 0-indexed index
'tK                 '# Remove all "t"
'…§¦                '# Push string "teen", and remove the first character: "een"
    '+              '# Push string "+"
      T«             # Append 10: "+10"
        :            # Replace all "een" with "+10"
'°¡                 '# Push string "hundred"
   „ *               # Push string " *"
      т«             # Append 100: " *100"
        ©            # Store it in the register (without popping)
         :           # Replace all "hundred" with " *100"
.•4º»Ÿć'Rþн•        '# Push string "wenhirforfif"
            3ô       # Split the string into parts of size 3: ["wen","hir","for","fif"]
              Ž9o    # Push integer 2345
                 S   # Split to digits: [2,3,4,5]
                  :  # Replace each
'y                  '# Push string "y"
  ®                  # Push the " *100" from the register
   ¨                 # Remove the last character: " *10"
    :                # Replace all "y" with " *10"
©                    # Save the current string in the register (without popping)
 “‰´Øè„Æ€ººß“        # Push string "plus minus times time divided"
             'tK    '# Remove all "t": "plus minus imes ime divided"
                #    # Split by spaces: ["plus","minus","imes","ime","divided"]
                 U   # Pop and save it in variable `X`
                  X  # And push variable `X` back again
                   ¡ # Split the string by those operator-strings
ε          }         # Map each substring to:
 ð¡                  #  Split by spaces (NOTE: cannot be `#`; if the string contains no
                     #   spaces, `#` remains string, whereas `ð¡` wraps it in a list)
   õK                #  Remove empty strings from the list
     2ô              #  Split the list into parts of two
       J             #  Join each pair together
        .E           #  Evaluate each as a Python `eval` expression
          O          #  Sum them
®                    # Put the string from the register to the stack again
 á                   # Remove everything except for letters
  X                  # Push variable `X`: ["plus","minus","imes","ime","divided"]
   "+-**/"           # Push string "+-**/"
          S          # Split to characters: ["+","-","*","*","/"]
           :         # Replace each
S                    # Split the string of operators to loose characters
 ðì                  # Prepend a space before each
   .ι                # Interweave all sums with these operator-characters
     J               # Join everything together to a single string
.E                   # Evaluate each as a Python `eval` expression (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?*, *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*, and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how `“¡×€µ‚•„í†ìˆÈŒšï¿Ÿ¯¥Š—¿áÓÁÏ“`, `'…§`, `'°¡`, `.•4º»Ÿć'Rþн•`, `Ž9o`, and `“‰´Øè„Æ€ººß“` work.

**Step by step example:**

- **Input:** `two hundred twenty two divided by two times minus fifty seven plus three hundred eighteen minus minus ten`
- Step 1: Remove "by": `two hundred twenty two divided  two times minus fifty seven plus three hundred eighteen minus minus ten`
- Step 2: Convert "zero" through "twelve" with the correct number: `2 hundred twenty 2 divided  2 times minus fifty 7 plus 3 hundred 8een minus minus 10`
- Step 3: Remove all "t": `2 hundred weny 2 divided  2 imes minus fify 7 plus 3 hundred 8een minus minus 10`
- Step 4: Replace all "een" with "+10": `2 hundred weny 2 divided  2 imes minus fify 7 plus 3 hundred 8+10 minus minus 10`
- Step 5: Replace all "hundred" with " *100": `2  *100 weny 2 divided  2 imes minus fify 7 plus 3  *100 8+10 minus minus 10`
- Step 6: Replace all ["wen","hir","for","fif"] with the correct digit: `2  *100 2y 2 divided  2 imes minus 5y 7 plus 3  *100 8+10 minus minus 10`
- Step 7: Replace all "y" with " *10": `2  *100 2 *10 2 divided  2 imes minus 5 *10 7 plus 3  *100 8+10 minus minus 10`
- Step 8: Split by ["plus","minus","ime","imes","divided"]: `["2  *100 2 *10 2 ","  2 "," "," 5 *10 7 "," 3  *100 8+10 "," "," 10"]`
- Step 9: Split each on spaces: `[["2","","*100","2","*10","2",""],["","","2",""],["",""],["","5","*10","7",""],["","3","","*100","8+10",""],["",""],["","10"]]`
- Step 10: Remove empty items: `[["2","*100","2","*10","2"],["2"],[],["5","*10","7"],["3","*100","8+10"],[],["10"]]`
- Step 11: Split into parts of size 2 and join: `[["2*100","2*10","2"],["2"],"",["5*10","7"],["3*100","8+10"],"",["10"]]`
- Step 12: Python `eval` each: `[[200,20,2],[2],"",[50,7],[300,18],"",[10]]`
- Step 13: Sum each: `[222,2,"",57,318,"",10]`
- Step 14: Re-push the string from the register, and remove everything except letters: `dividedimesminusplusminusminus`
- Step 15: Replace "plus","minus","imes","ime","divided" with the operator characters, and prepend them with a space: `[" /"," *"," -"," +"," -"," -"]`
- Step 16: Interweave and join both together: `222 /2 * -57 +318 - -10`
- **Output:** Python `eval` the string, and output implicitly: `-5999.0`

Comment: Haven't tried to make a solution from scratch or studied yours in detail, but I noticed [one golf](https://tio.run/##PU9PSwJREP8qLz0srKxRndq7F4U6WOA12We@yN1wn8oehJcH6RZUZESUK2RFlh40Qghhpj0FQl/hfZFtFqHLMPOb@f0Zzz8oCx7HWt2Xg4JWdxBiT3dGMNPqVqsB4fimVR9HP108iy6iEMewiD5hDI9RX6srWGCIl3iK50RON4Mdu23IgqHVEJ5gaGT24NU2YAKhYf52qM@S6Ab2jrSae2vfXbymeQun0de2V7SNgPyYmXDghfS0msAUb/A5idFNYs1hjg@0IY/0fgnC5QxJG2eFTZzms7ndNrxjWEplLNNcTxXtIn2x/MjniW9ZlMlilp3NxbFseazacJ06d5hscVcGLIEc0RQOQeXVKEWN@6wm3IbPKqJCRz5vcpedHBMgq3XO/0W4OKxKTrvV9apK7v4B).

Answer (score 2):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), <s>572</s> <s>449</s> 423 bytes

This could all be one line, but for the purposes of reading it I used newlines instead of spaces.

```
xed -i
_plus_+_
_minus_-_
_times[ortext]time_*_
_divided?by_/_
+xed
"_[white][2 chars of a-z][chars of a-z]ty_[parts 1,2]0_"
"_[white][2 chars of a-z][chars of a-z]een_[part1]1[part2]_"
_ten_10_
_lev_11_
_twe_12_
+xed
_ze_0_
_on_1_
_tw_2_
_th_3_
_fo_4_
_fi_5_
_si_6_
_se_7_
_ei_8_
_ni_9_
+xed
_0[white][keep][digit]__
"_[chars of e-z ]__"
+xed
"_?dd[keep][2 digits]_[part1]_"
_?dd[keep][digit]_[part1]0_
_dd_00_
+calc #text
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLBbtswDL3rK4Tstixo7G3deuqHGAKRRnRN1JUCS3Hi/HxGUra7Ypdd/CjyPeqRcmrf7vcrersjA6f@nGALBt4pcLTjKNM7piYOGa/ZyQG@ctbTSB7988sED2C2rDcbaC4dZXRNbY/dYUg2tvawu7nm0ylP0JwOQ062@la7PWz@V4gYirJylWLtWAyZ09WeLfU4QlWJ4wtCVc@u4IYg1cgsrUEt0MF3hjbCDwGCnwyJ4FEA4RcDEvxmCARPS6v94vMN8eQaT6@UHYAMsDrF3c1ybrPs5Nn7mV5bFSS3TCHuP8pzt7kmlr2HPeP2eOiP9ovs/35v43mw@iS2pRENzxryZOXdONFmXpIRXFMjLnRWGn1WG0NJ2kAB87Q0kXQhlK8qCsXO721fJpsv0awdEo4YbHcOfuCq5pcD9lort7OoOMrdgB@c3NHA3TX5Sazc1a1po9B0mtKF26099IIbDtGo43JD0f4TG/5dTHEmY/eyQvGge2P1ukDBRNeCQtcI6bXTQNcigZj@e/t/AA)